# Fastest way to duplicate an array in JavaScript - slice vs. 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, copy, slice

In order to duplicate an array in JavaScript: Which of the following is faster to use?

#### `Slice` method

```
var dup_array = original_array.slice();
```

#### `For` loop

```
for(var i = 0, len = original_array.length; i < len; ++i)
   dup_array[i] = original_array[i];
```

---

I know both ways do only a **shallow copy**: if `original_array` contains references to objects, objects won't be cloned, but only the references will be copied, and therefore both arrays will have references to the same objects.
But this is not the point of this question.

I'm asking only about speed.

Comment: http://jsben.ch/#/wQ9RU <= a benchmark for the most common ways to clone an array

Comment: See also [javascript - Copy array by value - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value) -- (some answer in that question does performance comparison)

Comment: Has anyone tried benchmarking using a specific function that returns the desired array? E.g. `const getInitialArray = () => {return [[1, 2], [3, 4]}`

Answer (score 910, accepted):

There are at least **6** (!) ways to clone an array:

- loop
- `slice`
- `Array.from()`
- `concat`
- spread syntax (FASTEST)
- map `A.map(function(e){return e;});`

There has been a huuuge [BENCHMARKS thread](http://jsben.ch/lO6C5), providing following information:

- for **blink** browsers `slice()` is the fastest method, `concat()` is a bit slower, and `while loop` is 2.4x slower.
- for other browsers `while loop` is the fastest method, since those browsers don't have internal optimizations for `slice` and `concat`.

This remains true in Jul 2016.

Below are simple scripts that you can copy-paste into your browser's console and run several times to see the picture. They output milliseconds, lower is better.

**while loop**

```
n = 1000*1000;
start = + new Date();
a = Array(n); 
b = Array(n); 
i = a.length;
while(i--) b[i] = a[i];
console.log(new Date() - start);
```

**slice**

```
n = 1000*1000;
start = + new Date();
a = Array(n); 
b = a.slice();
console.log(new Date() - start);
```

Please note that these methods will clone the Array object itself, array contents however are copied by reference and are not deep cloned.

```
origAr == clonedArr //returns false
origAr[0] == clonedArr[0] //returns true
```

Comment: well done! This might be the best answer now. Would you be able to explain why the simple test done by lincolnk (it's the above answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3978716/260080 ) gives out the opposite result, where `slice` is the faster than looping? I'm wondering if it's caused by the the type of elements in the array, in his test they were all numbers, in your are a mix of strings and objects.

Comment: Marco, you are quite right, storing data of one type speeds up an array. Google has written this somewhere, but you can always check it out http://jsperf.com/new-array-vs-splice-vs-slice/25 yourself

However, the biggest difference makes the concrete engine realisation. Algorithms evolve from build to build. On the other hand we can predict evolution when knowing the engine architecture. @lincolnk's benchmarking results look similar to those http://jsperf.com/new-array-vs-splice-vs-slice/11, October '10 is somewhere close to Chrome 19 and FireFox 10. Oh, slice is shorter to type then concat :)

Comment: @cept0 no emotions, just benchmarks http://jsperf.com/new-array-vs-splice-vs-slice/31

Comment: @Dan So what? Your test case results: Firefox 30 nightly is still ~230% faster than Chrome. Check the source code of V8 for `splice` and you'll be surprised (while...)

Comment: [Sadly for short arrays the answer is vastly different](http://jsperf.com/new-array-vs-splice-vs-slice/72). For example cloning an array of listeners before calling each of them. Those arrays are often small, usually 1 element.

Comment: I tested today 2015-05-04, the fastest method in Chrome 42 for Windows and for Android is .concat()

Comment: Congrats for benchmarking, demonstrated answer, nice work

Comment: The charts in that benchmarks page show that at least since Chrome 34, the fastest method has been consistently the while loop pre-allocated. It beats all other methods on all browsers by a lot.

Comment: jsperf is down. Shitty to refer to it, post the data next time directly here.

Comment: You missed this method: `A.map(function(e){return e;});`

Comment: At least as of 9.1.2 Safari has the slice/concat perf improvements, which are about 20x faster than while.

Comment: You're writing about ***blink** browsers*. Isn't *blink* just a layout engine, mainly affecting HTML rendering, and thus unimportant? I thought we'd rather talk about V8, Spidermonkey and friends here. Just a thing that confused me. Enlighten me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: **WARNING**: `.slice`, `spread`, `concat`, `Array.from` will not clone object in the array. Use a loop or a deep clone lib

Comment: I run these tests https://jsperf.com/new-array-vs-splice-vs-slice/152 on Chrome and `slice(0)` is the fastest one, but I think `Array.from()` looks cleaner even if it's 22% slower.

Comment: Best way for me is new_array = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( old_array ) ). In this way all references are killed

Comment: You forgot type conversion! See my post below: function clone(arr) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr))} ;)
ALL other operations do not create clones, because you just change the base adress of the root element, not of the included objects.

Comment: …Why would you do `1000*1000`, instead of just typing out `1000000` or doing `1e6`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is assuming naive cases where the array only contains values that are the "same shaped" in terms of hidden classes, and therefor result in optimizations.

If you have an array of "different shaped" values, the results are definitively different (Array.from) is the fastest in this unoptimized case: https://jsben.ch/BKvvd

Comment: the results for the code [as shown] conflate the time to create the 'a' array with the time to make a copy. more clear timing if you move the a = Array(n) before start =;   That aside, b = a.concat() is waaay faster that either

Answer (score 330):

Technically `slice` *is* the fastest way. *However*, it is even faster if you add the `0` begin index.

```
myArray.slice(0);
```

is faster than

```
myArray.slice();
```

https://jsben.ch/F0SZ3

Comment: And is `myArray.slice(0,myArray.length-1);` faster than `myArray.slice(0);` ?

Comment: @jave.web you;ve just dropped last element of the array. Full copy is array.slice(0) or array.slice(0, array.length)

Comment: This is incorrect, at least on my machine and according to your own benchmarks.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: https://jsben.ch/56xWo - sometimes, `slice()` is faster, sometimes `slice(0)`, both only marginally so (in Firefox 56 and latest Vivaldi, Chrome-based). But `slice(0, length)` is always noticeably slower (except that it's the fastest in Firefox 87).

Comment: Doing like this is not cloning. It is still referential copy.

Answer (score 193):

what about es6 way?

```
arr2 = [...arr1];
```

Comment: if converted with babel:
`[].concat(_slice.call(arguments))`

Comment: Not sure where `arguments` is coming from... I think your babel output is conflating a few different features. It's more likely to be `arr2 = [].concat(arr1)`.

Comment: @SterlingArcher `arr2 = [].conact(arr1)` is different from `arr2 = [...arr1]`. `[...arr1]` syntax will convert hole to `undefined`. For example, `arr1 = Array(1); arr2 = [...arr1]; arr3 = [].concat(arr1); 0 in arr2 !== 0 in arr3`.

Comment: I tested this in my browser (Chrome 59.0.3071.115) against Dan's answer above. It was more than 10 times slower than .slice(). `n = 1000*1000;
start = + new Date();
a = Array(n); 
b = [...a];
console.log(new Date() - start); // 168`

Comment: Simplest way. JS got this only in 2015... what a crappy language it was before (still far from decent).

Comment: Still will not clone something like this: `[{a: 'a', b: {c: 'c'}}]`. If `c`'s value is changed  in the "duplicated" array, it will change in the original array, since it's just a referential copy, not a clone.

Comment: As @TranslucentCloud mentioned, there is still the refernce. I just had a very very confusing time where I was [...baseSet, ...baseSet] to duplicate an array (for a Memory game) and I finally found I had a reference situation. I used lodash's `cloneDeep` to clone my array of objects. Thought to revisit this post and comment... Next time I'll read all comments first!

Comment: It doesn't really matter but as of March 2020, slice (150,936,056 ops/sec ±3.17%) is ~5x faster than the spread operator (34,565,713 ops/sec ±4.69%) in Node.js.

Answer (score 54):

Easiest way to deep clone Array or Object:

```
var dup_array = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original_array))
```

Comment: Important note for beginners: because this depends upon JSON, this also inherits its limitations. Among other things, that means your array cannot contain `undefined` or any `function`s. Both of those will be converted to `null` for you during the `JSON.stringify` process. Other strategies, such as `(['cool','array']).slice()` will not change them but also do not deep clone objects within the array. So there is a tradeoff.

Comment: Very bad perf and don't work with special objects like DOM, date, regexp, function ... or prototyped objects. Don't support cyclic references. You should never use JSON for deep clone.

Comment: worst possible way! Only use if for some issue all other doesn't work. It's slow, it's resources intense and it has all JSON limitations already mentioned in comments. Can't imagine how it got 25 up-votes.

Comment: It deep copies arrays with primitives, and where properties are arrays with further primitives/arrays. For that it is ok.

Comment: it's sure easy and very well known solution, but I wonder if it's **fast**

Comment: I tested this in my browser (Chrome 59.0.3071.115) against Dan's answer above. It was nearly 20 times slower than .slice(). `n = 1000*1000;
start = + new Date();
a = Array(n); 
var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))
console.log(new Date() - start); // 221 `

Comment: It can't be fast, as it has to do a whole lot of serializing and parsing to and from text. If deep copy if the reason you are doing this, better get a good deep-copy lib and just do `array.map` using the deep copy lib to return a copy of the element

Answer (score 48):

## Fastest Way to Clone an Array

I made this very plain utility function to test the time that it takes to clone an array. It is not 100% reliable. However, it can give you a bulk idea as to how long it takes to clone an existing array:

```
function clone(fn) {
  const arr = [...Array(1000000)];
  console.time('timer');
  fn(arr);
  console.timeEnd('timer');
}
```

And tested different approaches:

```
1)   5.79ms -> clone(arr => Object.values(arr));
2)   7.23ms -> clone(arr => [].concat(arr));
3)   9.13ms -> clone(arr => arr.slice());
4)  24.04ms -> clone(arr => { const a = []; for (let val of arr) { a.push(val); } return a; });
5)  30.02ms -> clone(arr => [...arr]);
6)  39.72ms -> clone(arr => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)));
7)  99.80ms -> clone(arr => arr.map(i => i));
8) 259.29ms -> clone(arr => Object.assign([], arr));
9) Maximum call stack size exceeded -> clone(arr => Array.of(...arr));
```

---

**UPDATES**

1. Tests were made back in **2018**, so most likely, you'll get different results with current browsers.
2. Out of these methods, the best way to deep clone an array is by using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr))`
3. Do not use the above if your array might include functions as it will return `null`.
   *Thank you @GilEpshtain for this update*.

Comment: I tried benchmarking your answer and I got very different results: http://jsben.ch/o5nLG

Comment: @mesqueeb, the tests might change, depending on ur machine of course. However, feel free to update the answer with your test result. Nice work!

Comment: I like your answer a lot, however I try your test and get that `arr => arr.slice()` is the fastest.

Comment: Thank you for running these tests @GilEpshtain! The result will change, depending on your machine. I noted that above the attached clone function. I think the main takeaway is that some methods are substantially faster than others. Especially when dealing with large data. Is that make sense?

Comment: @LiorElrom, your update isn't correct, due to the fact that methods aren't serializable. For example: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([function(){}]))` will output `[null]`

Comment: Thanks @GilEpshtain, I didn't know that :) I'll make an update

Comment: Nice benchmark. I've tested this on my Mac in 2 browsers: Chrome Version 81.0.4044.113 and Safari Version 13.1 (15609.1.20.111.8) and fastest is spread operation: `[...arr]` with `4.653076171875ms` in Chrome and `8.565ms` in Safari. Second fast in Chrome is slice function `arr.slice()` with `6.162109375ms` and in Safari second is `[].concat(arr)` with `13.018ms`.

Comment: I get very different results on different browsers by using the link from @mesqueeb's comment. On Chrome, I get that `[...arr]` is the fastest followed closely by `arr.slice()`, on Firefox, I get that `arr.slice()` is by far the fastest, and on iOS Safari `arr.slice()` is the fastest followed closely by both `[].concat(arr)` and `[...arr]`. So if we look at all these browsers combined, `arr.slice()` is the fastest. Also, the test results vary from one time to the next even on the same browser, but each time on each browser `arr.slice()` seems to be not too bad.

Answer (score 37):

```
var cloned_array = [].concat(target_array);
```

Comment: Please explain what this does.

Comment: While this code snippet may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer.

Comment: I hate this kind of comments. It's obvious what it does!

Comment: A simple answer for a simple quetions, no big story to read. I like this kind of answers +1

Comment: "I'm asking only about speed" - This answer gives no indication on speed. That is the main question being asked. brandonscript has a good point. More information is needed to consider this an answer. But if it were a simpler question, this would be an excellent answer.

Comment: It is not cloning. It's still referential copy

Comment: It is cloning the array, but performing a shallow copy of the elements in it. This is however, normal. For deep clones we mostly specifically mention *deep* cloning. And actually, deep cloning is pretty rare. Because it's more complex than it at first seems to do deep cloning. This answer will work fantastic for primitives though. However, so does `var cloned_array = target_array.slice()`, which is shorter.

Answer (score 26):

I put together a quick demo: http://jsbin.com/agugo3/edit

My results on Internet Explorer 8 are 156, 782, and 750, which would indicate `slice` is much faster in this case.

Comment: Don't forget the additional cost of the garbage collector if you have to do this very fast a lot. I was copying each neighbour array for each cell in my cellular automata using slice and it was much slower than reusing a previous array and copying the values. Chrome indicated about 40% of the total time was spent garbage collecting.

Answer (score 21):

`a.map(e => e)` is another alternative for this job. As of today `.map()` is very fast (almost as fast as `.slice(0)`) in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

On the other hand, if an array is multi-dimensional, since arrays are objects and objects are reference types, none of the slice or concat methods will be a cure... So one proper way of cloning an array is an invention of `Array.prototype.clone()` as follows.

```js
Array.prototype.clone = function(){
  return this.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? e.clone() : e);
};

var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, [ 1, 2, [ 1, 2, 3 ], 4 , 5], 6 ],
    brr = arr.clone();
brr[4][2][1] = "two";
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
console.log(JSON.stringify(brr));
```

Comment: Not bad, but unfortunately this doesn't work if you have Object in your array :\
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myArray)) works better in this case.

Answer (score 18):

Fastest way to clone an Array of Objects will be using **spread operator**

```
var clonedArray=[...originalArray]
or
var clonedArray = originalArray.slice(0); //with 0 index it's little bit faster than normal slice()
```

but the objects inside that cloned array will still pointing at the old memory location. hence change to clonedArray objects will also change the orignalArray. So

```
var clonedArray = originalArray.map(({...ele}) => {return ele})
```

this will not only create new array but also the objects will be cloned to.

**disclaimer** if you are working with nested object in that case spread operator will work as SHALLOW CLONE. At that point better to use

```
var clonedArray=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalArray));
```

Comment: You are the only one who noticed the memory location. Extra points for that!!

Comment: Thank you so much for emphasizing the memory location. Actually, that's probably the main reason why you need a 'decoupled' array clone.

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x))` is always a bad idea. It's lossy, and there's no point whatsoever in making a round-trip through **text** if you're trying to clone structured information.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at: [link](http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1725165). It's not about speed, but comfort. Besides as you can see you can only use **slice(0)** on **primitive types**.

To make an independent copy of an array rather than a copy of the refence to it, you can use the array slice method.

Example:

> To make an independent copy of an array rather than a copy of the refence to it, you can use the array slice method.
>
> ```
> var oldArray = ["mip", "map", "mop"];
> var newArray = oldArray.slice();
> ```
>
> To copy or clone an object :
>
> ```
> function cloneObject(source) {
>     for (i in source) {
>         if (typeof source[i] == 'source') {
>             this[i] = new cloneObject(source[i]);
>         }
>         else{
>             this[i] = source[i];
>   }
>     }
> }
>
> var obj1= {bla:'blabla',foo:'foofoo',etc:'etc'};
> var obj2= new cloneObject(obj1);
> ```

Source: [link](http://www.hardcode.nl/subcategory_1/article_414-copy-or-clone-javascript-array-object)

Comment: The *primitive types* comment applies to the `for` loop in the question as well.

Comment: if I were copying an array of objects, I would expect the new array to reference the same objects rather than cloning the objects.

Answer (score 8):

ECMAScript 2015 way with the `Spread` operator:

Basic examples:

```
var copyOfOldArray = [...oldArray]
var twoArraysBecomeOne = [...firstArray, ..seccondArray]
```

Try in the browser console:

```
var oldArray = [1, 2, 3]
var copyOfOldArray = [...oldArray]
console.log(oldArray)
console.log(copyOfOldArray)

var firstArray = [5, 6, 7]
var seccondArray = ["a", "b", "c"]
var twoArraysBecomOne = [...firstArray, ...seccondArray]
console.log(twoArraysBecomOne);
```

#### References

- *[6 Great Uses of the Spread Operator](https://davidwalsh.name/spread-operator)*
- *[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)*

Comment: Probably the only thing that is fast with the spread is to type it. It is waaay less performant than other ways of doing it.

Comment: Please provide some links about your argument.

Answer (score 7):

As @Dan said "This answer becomes outdated fast. Use [benchmarks](https://jsperf.com/clone-array-3) to check the actual situation", there is one specific answer from jsperf that has not had an answer for itself: **while**:

```
var i = a.length;
while(i--) { b[i] = a[i]; }
```

had 960,589 ops/sec with the runnerup `a.concat()` at 578,129 ops/sec, which is 60%.

This is the lastest Firefox (40) 64 bit.

---

@aleclarson created a new, more reliable benchmark.

Comment: You should really link the jsperf. The one you are thinking of is broken, because a new array is created in every test case, except the 'while loop' test.

Comment: I made a new jsperf that is more accurate: https://jsperf.com/clone-array-3

Comment: 60% what? 60% faster?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: 587192 is ~60% (61.1...) of 960589.

Answer (score 7):

Benchmark time!

```js
function log(data) {
  document.getElementById("log").textContent += data + "\n";
}

benchmark = (() => {
  time_function = function(ms, f, num) {
    var z = 0;
    var t = new Date().getTime();
    for (z = 0;
      ((new Date().getTime() - t) < ms); z++)
      f(num);
    return (z)
  }

  function clone1(arr) {
    return arr.slice(0);
  }

  function clone2(arr) {
    return [...arr]
  }

  function clone3(arr) {
    return [].concat(arr);
  }

  Array.prototype.clone = function() {
    return this.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? e.clone() : e);
  };

  function clone4(arr) {
    return arr.clone();
  }


  function benchmark() {
    function compare(a, b) {
      if (a[1] > b[1]) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (a[1] < b[1]) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    }

    funcs = [clone1, clone2, clone3, clone4];
    results = [];
    funcs.forEach((ff) => {
      console.log("Benchmarking: " + ff.name);
      var s = time_function(2500, ff, Array(1024));
      results.push([ff, s]);
      console.log("Score: " + s);

    })
    return results.sort(compare);
  }
  return benchmark;
})()
log("Starting benchmark...\n");
res = benchmark();

console.log("Winner: " + res[0][0].name + " !!!");
count = 1;
res.forEach((r) => {
  log((count++) + ". " + r[0].name + " score: " + Math.floor(10000 * r[1] / res[0][1]) / 100 + ((count == 2) ? "% *winner*" : "% speed of winner.") + " (" + Math.round(r[1] * 100) / 100 + ")");
});
log("\nWinner code:\n");
log(res[0][0].toString());
```

```html
<textarea rows="50" cols="80" style="font-size: 16; resize:none; border: none;" id="log"></textarea>
```

> The benchmark will run for 10s since you click the button.

My results:

Chrome (V8 engine):

```
1. clone1 score: 100% *winner* (4110764)
2. clone3 score: 74.32% speed of winner. (3055225)
3. clone2 score: 30.75% speed of winner. (1264182)
4. clone4 score: 21.96% speed of winner. (902929)
```

Firefox (SpiderMonkey Engine):

```
1. clone1 score: 100% *winner* (8448353)
2. clone3 score: 16.44% speed of winner. (1389241)
3. clone4 score: 5.69% speed of winner. (481162)
4. clone2 score: 2.27% speed of winner. (192433)
```

> Winner code:

```
function clone1(arr) {
    return arr.slice(0);
}
```

> Winner engine:
>
> SpiderMonkey (Mozilla/Firefox)

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the browser. If you look in the blog post *[Array.prototype.slice vs manual array creation](http://weblogs.asp.net/alexeigorkov/archive/2008/02/18/array-prototype-slice-vs-manual-array-creation.aspx)*, there is a rough guide to performance of each:

[image]

Results:

[image]

Comment: `arguments` is not a proper array and he's using `call` to force `slice` to run on the collection. results may be misleading.

Comment: Yeh I meant to mention that in my post that these stats would probably change now with the broswers improving, but it gives a general idea.

Comment: @diugalde I think the only situation where posting code as a picture is acceptable is when the code is potentially dangerous and should not be copy-pasted. In this case though, it's quite ridiculous.

Answer (score 6):

There is a much cleaner solution:

```
var srcArray = [1, 2, 3];
var clonedArray = srcArray.length === 1 ? [srcArray[0]] : Array.apply(this, srcArray);
```

The length check is required, because the `Array` constructor behaves differently when it is called with exactly one argument.

Comment: But is it the fastest?

Comment: More semantic than `splice()`, perhaps. But really, _apply_ and _this_ is all but intuitive.

Comment: shows the slowest performance on chrome- http://jsperf.com/new-array-vs-splice-vs-slice/113

Comment: You can use `Array.of` and ignore the length: `Array.of.apply(Array, array)`

Answer (score 6):

Remember .slice() won't work for two-dimensional arrays. You'll need a function like this:

```
function copy(array) {
  return array.map(function(arr) {
    return arr.slice();
  });
}
```

Comment: In Javascript there aren't two-dimensional arrays. There are just arrays containing arrays. What you are trying to do is a *deep copy* which is not required in the question.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the length of the array. If the array length is <= 1,000,000, the `slice` and `concat` methods are taking approximately the same time. But when you give a wider range, the `concat` method wins.

For example, try this code:

```
var original_array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10000000; i ++) {
    original_array.push( Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000 + 1));
}

function a1() {
    var dup = [];
    var start = Date.now();
    dup = original_array.slice();
    var end = Date.now();
    console.log('slice method takes ' + (end - start) + ' ms');
}

function a2() {
    var dup = [];
    var start = Date.now();
    dup = original_array.concat([]);
    var end = Date.now();
    console.log('concat method takes ' + (end - start) + ' ms');
}

function a3() {
    var dup = [];
    var start = Date.now();
    for(var i = 0; i < original_array.length; i ++) {
        dup.push(original_array[i]);
    }
    var end = Date.now();
    console.log('for loop with push method takes ' + (end - start) + ' ms');
}

function a4() {
    var dup = [];
    var start = Date.now();
    for(var i = 0; i < original_array.length; i ++) {
        dup[i] = original_array[i];
    }
    var end = Date.now();
    console.log('for loop with = method takes ' + (end - start) + ' ms');
}

function a5() {
    var dup = new Array(original_array.length)
    var start = Date.now();
    for(var i = 0; i < original_array.length; i ++) {
        dup.push(original_array[i]);
    }
    var end = Date.now();
    console.log('for loop with = method and array constructor takes ' + (end - start) + ' ms');
}

a1();
a2();
a3();
a4();
a5();
```

If you set the length of original_array to 1,000,000, the `slice` method and `concat` method are taking approximately the same time (3-4 ms, depending on the random numbers).

If you set the length of original_array to 10,000,000, then the `slice` method takes over 60 ms and the `concat` method takes over 20 ms.

Comment: `dup.push` is wrong in `a5`, instead `dup[i] = ` should be used

Answer (score 4):

In ES6, you can simply utilize [the Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Example:

```
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let arr2 = [...arr];
```

Please note that the spread operator generates a completely new array, so modifying one won't affect the other.

Example:

```
arr2.push('d') // becomes ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
console.log(arr) // while arr retains its values ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        const arr = ['1', '2', '3'];

         // Old way
        const cloneArr = arr.slice();

        // ES6 way
        const cloneArrES6 = [...arr];

// But problem with 3rd approach is that if you are using muti-dimensional 
 // array, then only first level is copied

        const nums = [
              [1, 2], 
              [10],
         ];

        const cloneNums = [...nums];

// Let's change the first item in the first nested item in our cloned array.

        cloneNums[0][0] = '8';

        console.log(cloneNums);
           // [ [ '8', 2 ], [ 10 ], [ 300 ] ]

        // NOOooo, the original is also affected
        console.log(nums);
          // [ [ '8', 2 ], [ 10 ], [ 300 ] ]
```

So, in order to avoid these scenarios to happen, use

```
        const arr = ['1', '2', '3'];

        const cloneArr = Array.from(arr);
```

Comment: It's a valid thing to point out about how changing `cloneNums[0][0]` in your example propagated the change to `nums[0][0]` - but that's because the `nums[0][0]` is effectively an object whose reference is copied into `cloneNums` by the spread operator. All that is to say, this behaviour won't affect code where we are copying by value (int, string etc literals).

Answer (score 3):

There were several ways to clone an array. Basically, Cloning was categorized in two ways:

1. **Shallow copy**
2. **Deep copy**

> Shallow copies only cover the 1st level of the array and the rest are
> referenced. If you want a true copy of nested elements in the arrays, you’ll need a
> deep clone.

Example :

```
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]           
// Normal Array (shallow copy is enough)     
const arr2 = [1,2,3,[4],[[5]],6,7]          
// Nested Array  (Deep copy required) 


Approach 1 : Using (...)Spread Operator  (Shallow copy enough)
const newArray = [...arr1] // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

Approach 2 : Using Array builtIn Slice method (Deep copy)  
const newArray = arr1.slice()  // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

Approach 3 : Using Array builtIn Concat method (Deep a copy)
const newArray = [].concat(arr1)  // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

Approach 4 : Using JSON.stringify/parse. (Deep a copy & fastest)
const newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr2));)  // [1,2,3,[4],[[5]],6,7]

Approach 5: Using own recursive function or using loadash's __.cloneDeep method. (Deep copy)
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution:

```
original = [1,2,3]
cloned = original.map(x=>x)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Fast ways to duplicate an array in JavaScript in Order:**

**`#1: array1copy = [...array1];`**

**`#2: array1copy = array1.slice(0);`**

**`#3: array1copy = array1.slice();`**

**If your array objects contain some JSON-non-serializable content (functions, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, etc.) better to use**

**`array1copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array1))`**

Answer (score 1):

**You can follow this code. Immutable way array clone. This is the perfect way to array cloning**

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

const newArray = [...array]
newArray.push(6)
console.log(array)
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a REAL cloned object/array in JS with cloned references of all attributes and sub-objects:

```
export function clone(arr) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr))
}
```

ALL other operations do not create clones, because they just change the base address of the root element, not of the included objects.

Except you traverse recursive through the object-tree.

For a simple copy, these are OK. For storage address relevant operations I suggest (and in most all other cases, because this is fast!) to type convert into string and back in a complete new object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking about **slice** it is used to copy elements from an array and create a clone with same no. of elements or less no. of elements.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3 , 4, 5];

function slc() {
  var sliced = arr.slice(0, 5);
// arr.slice(position to start copying master array , no. of items in new array)
  console.log(sliced);
}
slc(arr);
```