# Splice an array in half, no matter the size?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array I would like to split in half.  So I can position the first half on the right side and the second half on the left side.

I have used the splice function before:

```
var leftSide = arrayName.splice(0,2);
```

But not sure how to splice it in half no matter the size, because the array will change in size dynamically.

Comment: How might you find how large you want each half to be?

Comment: -1 because you can determine that just by thinking about it. What will the halfway point -- the argument to `splice` -- be when the array size is `N`? And how do you determine `N`?

Comment: what if there's an odd number? There is no 'Half'.... just sayin!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
var half_length = Math.ceil(arrayName.length / 2);    

var leftSide = arrayName.slice(0,half_length);
```

edited the code following @Lightness Races in Orbit and @pubkey comments.

Comment: `Math.ceil(arrayName.length / 2)` can replace seven and a third lines of your code, and avoid contaminating the global scope to boot.

Comment: This is dangerous because it mutates the original array 'arrayName'. You can prevent this by first calling slice(0) to copy the original array like arrayName.slice(0).splice(0, halfLength);

Answer (score 77):

## Avoid Mutations

If you need to avoid mutations, for example if you have to split an array in react you don't want to mutate the original or it could lead to some very strange behaviour in your app.

### What is a Mutation?

A mutation is when you change a non primitive, like an object or array. Using an array method like splice will cause the original array to be manipulated. You can always tell if a method will mutate by whether or not it returns a new array or object.

### Why can Mutations be "bad"?

When you mutate an object or array you change that original reference. This means that if you use the original reference you will get the new value. This is best shown with an example.

```
// make a new object
const myObj = { key: "some value" };

// assign a new const to the object (this is assigned by reference)
const newObj = myObj;

// change the value of a key in the new const
newObj.key = "some other value";

// log the original object and see that its value has been changed
console.log(myObj) // will log { key: "some other value" };
```

As you can see the object `myObj` had the value of key changed as well. Scary stuff.

## Use Slice

You can get around this by using `slice` instead of `splice`

## Example

```
let yourArray = props.someArray;
let halfwayThrough = Math.floor(yourArray.length / 2)
// or instead of floor you can use ceil depending on what side gets the extra data

let arrayFirstHalf = yourArray.slice(0, halfwayThrough);
let arraySecondHalf = yourArray.slice(halfwayThrough, yourArray.length);
```

Comment: @NSjonas yes mutations are a real pain, can lead to really insane behaviour in your application.

Comment: Thanks. I'm also reading props in a React app so this answer was perfect for me

Comment: the very last `yourArray.length` is not required. “till the end” [is default](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)

Comment: Why use `Math.floor()` ? it can work without it

Comment: @Thomas you will get .5 if you have an uneven number of ites in your array making the slice unusable.

Answer (score 23):

You can simply refer to the array's length:

```
var leftSide = arrayName.splice(0, Math.floor(arrayName.length / 2));
```

Since `.splice()` actually removes elements from the source array, the remaining elements in the array will be the elements for the right half.

`Math.floor()` will round down to give the left side one less than the right side for odd lengths.  You could use `Math.ceil()` if you want to round up to give the left side one more than the right side when the length is odd.

Answer (score 6):

You can use ES6 destructing also and **slice()** so that the original array isn't mutated.

```
   const yourArray;
   let leftSide,rightSide;
   const m = Math.floor(yourArray.length/2);
   const [leftSide,rightSide] = [yourArray.slice(0,m), yourArray.slice(m,yourArray.length)];
   console.log(leftSide);
   console.log(rightSide);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
let leftSide = myArray.splice(0, Math.ceil(myArray.length / 2));
//The right side is stored in "myArray"
```

For example:

```
let letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
let leftSide = letters.splice(0, Math.ceil(letters.length /2));
let rightSide = letters;
console.log(leftSide);
=> ['a', 'b', 'c']
console.log(rightSide);
=> ['d', 'e']
```

**More information:** [**`splice`** in the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

---

Note that this modifies your original array. If you want to keep the original array, clone the array, then use splice on the cloned array.
From an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/javascript-fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-slice-vs-for-loop) about cloning arrays:

> There has been a huuuge BENCHMARKS thread, providing following information:
>
> - **for blink browsers slice() is the fastest method**, concat() is a bit slower, and while loop is 2.4x slower.
> - **for other browsers while loop is the fastest method**, since those browsers don't have internal optimizations for slice and concat.

```
//Fastest for Blink browsers (Opera/Chromium):
let clonedArray = originalArray.slice();
//For other browsers:
let clonedArray = [];
var i = myArray.length;
while (i--) clonedArray[i] = myArray[i];
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at lodash [`chunk`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#chunk):

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var pivot = _.ceil(myArray.length / 2);
// => 4
console.log(_.chunk(myArray, pivot));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a fun function for **Avoiding Mutations** with options:

```
function splitArray({ alternate, array }) {
  const halfIndex = Math.ceil(array.length / 2) - 1;
  let firstArray = true;
  return array.reduce((res, item, index) => {
    if (firstArray) {
      res[0].push(item);
      if (alternate || index >= halfIndex) {
        firstArray = false;
      }
    } else {
      res[1].push(item);
      if (alternate) {
        firstArray = true;
      }
    }
    return res;
  }, [[], []]);
}
```

And you can call it with an alternating option:

```
const myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
const splitAlternate = splitArray({ alternate: true, array: myArray });
const splitNoAlternate = splitArray({ alternate: false, array: myArray });

console.log(myArray);
console.log(splitAlternate);
console.log(splitNoAlternate);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the size of the array to stay equal you just need to alternate which array you write to (eg, alternate .push calls on the arrays)..
Why don't you just create 2 arrays up front?

```
var lelftHalf = yourArray.splice(0,arrayName.length / 2);
```

After you do that if you want to keep the 2 arrays the same size alternate between

```
leftHalf.push(newElement);
```

and

```
yourArray.push(newElement1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, you probably shouldn't use it though.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].reduce(([l, r], cur, i, self) => i < self.length / 2 ? [[...l, cur], r] : [l, [...r, cur]], [[], []])
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use filter as another available way to solve it.

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let half = arr.filter((el, i) => i >= arr.length/2);
```

Comment: This looks pretty imperformant, as you need to traverse the whole array

Comment: you could use the 3. parameter of the callback function instead (`arr.filter((el, i, self) => i >= self.length / 2)`)