# how to split an array into equal length arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I split an array into equal sized arrays:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var b = a.split(2);
// b is equal to [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]];
// one possible way might be something like
[0,1,2,3].map(_ => a.slice(_* 2, _+2));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks

Comment: There is a discussion here:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181188/splice-an-array-in-half-no-matter-the-size].  Kind of interesting what to do if the array has an odd number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const chunk = (arr, size) => arr.reduce((carry, _, index, orig) => !(index % size) ? carry.concat([orig.slice(index,index+size)]) : carry, []);

console.log(chunk([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

For the second index for splicing, you need to add one and multiply with the length of the inner arrays.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    b = [0, 1, 2, 3].map(i => a.slice(i * 2, (i + 1) * 2));

console.log(b);
```