# React (typescript): How to loop inside const creation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Beginner React/Typescript learner here, I am trying to improve this class I have:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Form, IFields, isEmail, required} from "../../components/Form";
import {Field} from "../../components/Field";

const API = '/api/getmonth';

export interface Props {
}

interface State {
  data: string[],
  isLoading: boolean,
  error: any,
}

class monthForm extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: false,
      error: null,
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({isLoading: true});

    fetch(API)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Error getting month list');
        }
      })
      .then(content => this.setState({data: content, isLoading: false}))
      .catch(error => this.setState({error, isLoading: false}));
  }

  render() {
    const {data, isLoading, error} = this.state;

    if (error) {
      return <p>{error.message}</p>;
    }
    if (isLoading) {
      return (
        <p>Loading ...</p>
      )
    }

    const fields: IFields = {
      jan: {
        id: "jan",
        label: "Jan",
        editor: "dropdown",
        options: data,
        value: "hello",
        validation: {rule: required}
      },
      feb: {
        id: "feb",
        label: "Feb",
        editor: "dropdown",
        options: data,
        value: "hello",
        validation: {rule: required}
      },
      mar: {
        id: "mar",
        label: "Mar",
        editor: "dropdown",
        options: data,
        value: "hello",
        validation: {rule: required}
      },
      apr: {
        id: "apr",
        label: "Apr",
        editor: "dropdown",
        options: data,
        value: "hello",
        validation: {rule: required}
      },
      may: {
        id: "may",
        label: "May",
        editor: "dropdown",
        options: data,
        value: "hello",
        validation: {rule: required}
      },
      jun: {
        id: "jun",
        label: "Jun",
        editor: "dropdown",
        options: data,
        value: "hello",
        validation: {rule: required}
      },
      jul: {
        id: "jul",
        label: "Jul",
        editor: "dropdown",
        options: data,
        value: "hello",
        validation: {rule: required}
      },
      aug: {
        id: "aug",
        label: "Aug",
        editor: "dropdown",
        options: data,
        value: "hello",
        validation: {rule: required}
      },
      sep: {
        id: "sep",
        label: "Sep",
        editor: "dropdown",
        options: data,
        value: "hello",
        validation: {rule: required}
      },
      oct: {
        id: "oct",
        label: "Oct",
        editor: "dropdown",
        options: data,
        value: "hello",
        validation: {rule: required}
      },
      nov: {
        id: "nov",
        label: "Nov",
        editor: "dropdown",
        options: data,
        value: "hello",
        validation: {rule: required}
      },
      dec: {
        id: "dec",
        label: "Dec",
        editor: "dropdown",
        options: data,
        value: "hello",
        validation: {rule: required}
      },
    };
    return (
      <Form
        action="/react/test/form"
        fields={fields}
        render={() => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <div className="alert alert-info" role="alert">
              Select Projection for each month
            </div>
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-3">
                  <Field {...fields.jan}/>
                  <Field {...fields.feb}/>
                  <Field {...fields.mar}/>
                  <Field {...fields.apr}/>
                  <Field {...fields.may}/>
                  <Field {...fields.jun}/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-3">
                  <Field {...fields.jul}/>
                  <Field {...fields.aug}/>
                  <Field {...fields.sep}/>
                  <Field {...fields.oct}/>
                  <Field {...fields.nov}/>
                  <Field {...fields.dec}/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default monthForm;
```

particularly this part:

```
      jan: {
        id: "jan",
        label: "Jan",
        editor: "dropdown",
        options: data,
        value: "hello",
        validation: {rule: required}
      },
      feb: {
        id: "feb",
        label: "Feb",
        editor: "dropdown",
        options: data,
        value: "hello",
        validation: {rule: required}
      },
      mar: {
        id: "mar",
        label: "Mar",
        editor: "dropdown",
        options: data,
        value: "hello",
        validation: {rule: required}
      },
      apr: {
        id: "apr",
        label: "Apr",
        editor: "dropdown",
        options: data,
        value: "hello",
        validation: {rule: required}
      },
      may: {
        id: "may",
        label: "May",
        editor: "dropdown",
        options: data,
        value: "hello",
        validation: {rule: required}
      },
```

This section seems like it could easily be looped over a const [] with month names. But I can't seem to find any reference on how to achieve it.

Any help or point to a reference example would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/keys) or [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

```
Object.values(fields).map(month => <Field {...month}/>)
```

If you want to separate the months, you can [split the array in half](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47777083/9119186) (`Object.values(fields)`) and render both separately.

```
render(){
    const months = Object.values(fields)
    const halfwayThrough = Math.floor(months.length / 2)
    const monthFirstHalf = months.slice(0, halfwayThrough);
    const monthSecondHalf = months.slice(halfwayThrough, months.length);

    ...

    return (
        ...
        <div className="col-md-3">
            {monthFirstHalf.map(month => <Field {...month}/>)}
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-3">
            {monthSecondHalf.map(month => <Field {...month}/>)}
        </div>
        ...
    )

}
```

## Edit:

Instead of having that huge object and supposing all the properties are the same except for the name, here is something you can do with [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) (you could also do with a `.forEach`)

```
const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', /* ...rest */] 
const fields = months.reduce((monthObject, monthName) => {
    let monthId = monthName.toLowerCase()
    monthObject[monthId] = {
        id: monthId,
        label: monthName,
        editor: "dropdown",
        options: data,
        value: "hello",
        validation: {rule: required}
    }
    return monthObject
}, {})
```

And with this, you will have created that huge object

Combining both thins, here is what you can do

```
const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', /* ...rest */] 

return (
   ...
   {months.map(month => <Field 
           id={month}
           label={month}
           editor: "dropdown",
           options: data,
           value: "hello",
           validation: {rule: required}
       />
   )}
   ...
)
```

Comment: Or [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (for completeness)

Comment: thanks, do you have any tips on how to loop the `const fields: IFields = {...}` part (second code block)? if I understand correctly that is just an array but I want to insert to it in a loop rather than declare the whole thing that is mostly duplicates with different key, thanks!

Comment: @tom I didn't understand what you want. You want something like having an array with the month name and create that huge fields object?

Comment: @tom check my edit, maybe that is what you need, please tell me if my assumptions are right or not.

Comment: @Vencovsky yes exactly, I will have a `let month = ["jan", "feb", "mar"]` and do a `month.map(...)` over it, ideally i would be able to create that huge `fields` object within this loop

Comment: thanks so much everything works now! time to understand the map.reduce part!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are thinking about refactoring the creation of a list of objects by looping over a list of month names. Vencovsky shows how to use `reduce()` to do this. I would go a step further and create the `<Field>` components directly by using `map()`:

```
const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', /* ...rest */] 
const monthFields = months.map(m => 
   <Field id={m}
      label={m}
      editor="dropdown"
      options={data}
      value="hello"
      validation={{rule: required}} />
);
```