# Copying a javascript array inside a class protoype function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this class on javascript:

```
function Node(board,x,y,t){
    this.board = board;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.playerTile = t;
    this.oponentTile = getOponentTile(this.playerTile);
    this.parent = null;
    this.getChildren = getChildren;

};
```

and I´m using this function which copies the `this.board` variable (which is an array) to the `tempBoard` variable using `slice()`

```
var getChildren = function() {
        if(this.x==-1 && this.y ==-1){
            var moves = getAllValidMoves(this.board,this.playerTile);
        }
        else{
            var tempBoard = this.board.slice();
            makeMove(tempBoard,this.playerTile,this.x,this.y);
            var moves = getAllValidMoves(tempBoard,this.playerTile);
        }

        var children = [];
        for(var i = 0;i<moves.length;i++){
            var currentMove = moves[i];
            var currentBoard = this.board.slice();
            if(this.x==-1 && this.y ==-1){
                children.push(new Node(currentBoard,currentMove[0],currentMove[1],this.playerTile));
            }
            else{
                makeMove(currentBoard,this.playerTile,this.x,this.y)
                children.push(new Node(currentBoard,currentMove[0],currentMove[1],this.oponentTile));
            }

        }
        return children;
    };
```

the problem is that after calling `makemove()` both the `tempBoard` and the `this.board` variables are being modified.

Is there any way I can copy an array without it´s reference?

Comment: So you want  a deep copy? `.slice()` only does a shallow copy.

Comment: var tempBoard = []; this.board.slice().forEach(function(b){tempBoard.push(b)});

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo: That's no different.

Comment: What type of data is in the array `this.board`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.slice()` makes a shallow copy of the array, not a deep copy.

That means that if you have an array of objects and you use `.slice()` to make a copy of the array, it gives you a new array that is a first level copy.  But the new array points to all the same objects as the first array.  You can rearrange the copied array or remove elements from it and that will not affect the first array.

But, if you modify the objects in the array, it is the same objects in both arrays so making a modification to any object in the array (such as changing a property on the object) will be seen in both arrays.

If you want a full copy of the array and it's contents, then you have to make a deep copy which is a bit more complicated and can slightly depend upon what exactly you have in the array.

There are many different ways to make a deep copy.  You can read about many of them in these references:

[How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object/728694#728694)

[Copying an array of objects into another array in javascript (Deep Copy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482593/copying-an-array-of-objects-into-another-array-in-javascript-deep-copy)

[Copying array by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript/23536726#23536726)

If you are guaranteed not to have any circular references in your array (where one object points to another which points back to it), then the simplest way to make a copy is this:

```
var tempBoard = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.board));
```

Comment: Ohh that´s interesting. Then yes, I need a deep copy. My array contains just strings.

Comment: @PabloEstrada - Are you sure the array contains just strings?  Because strings are immutable in Javascript so a `.slice()` would make a copy just fine.  Can you show us what is actually in the array and why you think both are getting changed?

Comment: I´m sorry, my mistake. I have an array of arrays of strings. Like this  `[[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']]`

Comment: @PabloEstrada - Then you do need a deep copy.  I added several references to methods for making the deep copy and one example.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer :) The stringify worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

maybe help

```
function copy(data){
    var result = JSON.stringify(data);
    return JSON.parse(result);
}
```