# Aborting all ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've implemented the usual AJAX pool, but when I abort all requests it aborts them at increments of 2 requests, ie. first, third, fifth ...
This is basically what I do:

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
    $.xhrPool.push(jqXHR);
  },
  complete: function(jqXHR, text) {
    // Remove a completed request from the array
    var index = $.xhrPool.indexOf(jqXHR);
    if (index > -1) {
      $.xhrPool.splice(index, 1);
    }
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Remove a error request from the array
    var index = $.xhrPool.indexOf(jqXHR);
    if (index > -1) {
      $.xhrPool.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
});

function abortAll() {
  $.each($.xhrPool, function(key, value) {
    value.abort();
  });
}
```

If I do a `console.log(value)` inside the `$.each`, some of them are undefined. If I do a `console.log($.xhrPool)` before the `$.each`, they all look ok.

What am I missing?

Comment: As you're aborting them, are the complete and error callback happening synchronously? I would expect not, but, maybe

Comment: You can use complete instead to remove the item to keep your code DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Gaby aka G. Petrioli answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47819123/209259), the best way to actually solve this problem is to create a new array to loop over:

```
function abortAll() {
  // copying-an-array-of-objects-into-another-array-in-javascript
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232915
  var calls = Array.from($.xhrPool);

  $.each(calls, function(key, value) {
    value.abort();
  });
}
```

Comment: Creating a static instance of xhrPool using Array.from did the trick

Answer (score 2):

First of all the `complete` is called even after an `error` so you do not need to handle both if you do the same thing.

Secondly, when you abort the `error` and `complete` are invoked so the initial array is altered while you are iterating over it (*in the `$.each`*) which is a bad pattern in general.

So in your `each` you are at the 1st element, you abort it *(and alter the array to remove the element*), then you go to the element with index 2 which is the previously 3rd but now 2nd since the 1st was removed.

```
Array                      each index                target
[xhr1, xhr2, xhr3, xhr4]       0                      xhr1
[xhr2, xhr3, xhr4]             1                      xhr3
[xhr3, xhr4]                   2                      undefined
```

Comment: Are you use javascript can run multiple scripts in parallel?  If not, it's not possible for error nor complete to run while abortAll

Comment: @ErikPhilips they are not run in parallel. Inside the jquery `.abort()` method the `.complete()` is called.

Comment: Gotcha, you are correct, I see what you're saying now.  You probably should include an coded answer to solve the problem.