# Javascript array copying, concat vs slice, which one is better?

Tags: javascript

there are two different ways to copy a array, using Array.concat or Array.slice,

for example:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3],

    c1 = [].concat(a),

    c2 = a.slice(0);
```

which way is better?

Comment: What do you mean by better

Comment: `arr.slice()` might be faster , just benchmark it .http://jsperf.com/duplicate-array-slice-vs-concat/3

Comment: check this out http://jsperf.com/duplicate-array-slice-vs-concat/3 slice is faster

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/javascript-fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-slice-vs-for-loop


For all I've read, slice is faster.

Comment: @Esailija  which way you will use, and why

Comment: What about `c3 = a.concat()`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For clarity, you should use the method that is the *documented* method of taking a copy of an array (or portion thereof):

```
var c2 = a.slice(0);
```

On any decent browser the performance difference will be negligible, so clarity should be the deciding factor.

Comment: Documented where?

Comment: @ericsoco https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice - _"The `slice()` method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from `begin` to `end` (`end` not included). The original array will not be modified."_

Answer (score 5):

In terms of performance, the difference between the two options are minimal, according to a [jsperf.com test](http://jsperf.com/duplicate-array-slice-vs-concat/3).