# Make non-destructive the splice of JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to make the `splice()` non-destructive?

What I need to do is to retain the `arr2` as it is after I call the function.

```
function foo(arr1, arr2, n) {
   let result = arr2;
   result.splice(n, 0, ...arr1.slice(0, arr1.length));
   console.log(arr2);
}

foo(["I'm", "not", "done"], ["sorry", "yet"], 1);
```

Although it returns `sorry,I'm,not,done,yet` which is what **I want but the elements of `arr2` shouldn't change**.

Comment: Use `slice` instead of `splice`. Same syntax, but not "destructive".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can (shallow) copy the array before modifying it with  `.concat`.

```
let result = [].concat(arr2);
// ... modify result...
```

Comment: As a sidenote: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17803586/1169798 . I'd also prefer `slice()` to make copies for readability reasons.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "non destructive" function, AKA `slice` :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Here's a SO question with the difference between slice and splice : [JavaScript Array splice vs slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601282/javascript-array-splice-vs-slice)

The syntax is the exact same, so you just have to remove one letter

```
function foo(arr1, arr2, n) {
   let result = arr2;
   result.slice(n, 0, ...arr1.slice(0, arr1.length));
   console.log(arr2);
}

foo(["I'm", "not", "done"], ["sorry", "yet"], 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

You can use [array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

Please find below example:

```js
function foo(arr1, arr2, n) {
  let result = [].concat(arr2);
  result.splice(n, 0, ...arr1.slice(0, arr1.length));
  console.log(arr2);
  console.log(result);
}

foo(["I'm", "not", "done"], ["sorry", "yet"], 1);
```

**Option 2:**

Using [array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) mentioned in comment above by @Seblor like this `let result = arr2.slice();`

Example below:

```js
function foo(arr1, arr2, n) {
  let result = arr2.slice();
  result.splice(n, 0, ...arr1.slice(0, arr1.length));
  console.log(arr2);
  console.log(result);
}

foo(["I'm", "not", "done"], ["sorry", "yet"], 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Slice function without parameter makes a (shallow) copy of an array .

```
let result = arr2.slice();
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function you can also use the spread operator (in case you are using ES2015) to create a copy of `arr2`:

`let result = [...arr2];`