# JavaScript object property gets modified in a very interesting way

Tags: javascript

I have put together a small test, can someone explain why does JavaScript do the following?

Why will `testArr` inherit the modifications of `newArray`?

```
var TestClass = function() {

            this.testArr = [10,11];

            this.addToArray = function() {
                var newArray = this.testArr;
                newArray.push(12);
            }
        }

        var testClass = new TestClass();

        testClass.addToArray();

        console.log(testClass.testArr); // will be [10, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because they're the same array. Variables contain references to arrays. You're assigning that reference to a new variable, and now both variables point to the same array.

Here's a much simpler test which reproduces the behavior:

```
x = [1, 2]     // the value of x is a reference to an array
y = x          // the value of y is a reference to the same array
y.push(3)      // modify the array pointed to by both variables
console.log(x) // [1, 2, 3]
```

If you want to create a new array, you need to [clone the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/javascript-fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-slice-vs-for-loop).

Comment: What can I do to avoid it? really interesting

Comment: Ty very much, what do you think is the best way to clone the array?

Comment: I included a link in my answer which explains it pretty clearly.

Answer (score 0):

With following statement

```
var newArray = this.testArr;
```

You **will not** copy the values from inside testArr. You will create a reference to this array. When you make an adjustment to a reference you will automatically change the referenced source too.

When you want to copy the values from testArr to another variable you can do this instead.

```
var newArray = this.testArr.slice();
```

This will copy the values from testArr inside newArray.