# Another way to get all combination of integers of an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, time-complexity

I want to iterate an array and find all pairs where their difference is 2

This is what i have so far:

```
var numberOfCases = 5;
var diff = 2;

var input = [1,5,3,4,2];

getPossiblepairs(input);

function getPossiblepairs(input){
    for(cmp in input){
        for(number in input){
            if((input[cmp] - input[number]) == diff){
                console.log("("+input[cmp]+","+input[number]+")");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This works but i still feel guilty using two for loops as the bigO is **O(n^2)** Is this the only way to do this?

Comment: There may be algorithms you can do to get better, if you actually know the distribution of numbers (here they are a sequential series, although out of order). But with just 5 entries, so 25 iterations O(5^2), do you really care to get it more efficient than that?

Comment: I changed the wording to ask for other methods, as 'best way' is going to be closed as primarily opinion based.

Comment: Sort the list whuch is O(N) log n. The one that has a differencee of two from the current one is either the next element, or the one after that. That's an O(1) check. Checking all of them is O(N). So overall O(N log N)

Comment: @Paul that only works if the numbers aren't repeated

Comment: Another O(N) Pass to put equal elements into counted buckets would fix that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in **O(n log n)**. Sort the array then go through it in a single pass. Find the difference between the current element and each of the next two, printing out the pair if one is different by 2.

Comment: what he said.  beat me by a minute

Comment: @Doug i'm currently trying to implementing your solution, but wouldn't the difference between each next two element always remain 1 ?

Comment: Hi @Pizzy213codes, with your example, after the sort phase there'd be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. The first step is to compare 1 to 2 and 1 to 3.  The diff is 1 in the first case, 2 in the second.  If there were any non-consecutive numbers like [1, 5, 7, 22], then the differences will get bigger.  I'm guessing you figured it out, though!

Answer (score 4):

This should work with a *n log n* complexity:

```
function getPossiblepairs(input, diff){
    // Create a copy of the original array, so it is not affected by the next operation
    var sortedInput = input.slice();
    // Sort the array
    sortedInput.sort();
    // Iterate through the array, starting from the 0th element
    for (var i=0, n=sortedInput.length; i<n; i++){
        firstNumber = sortedInput[i];
        // Iterate through the array, starting from the (i+1)th element
        for (var j=i+1; j<n && sortedInput[j] <= firstNumber + diff; j++){
            secondNumber = sortedInput[j];
            // if it matches, then log it!
            if (secondNumber - firstNumber == diff){
                console.log('(' + firstNumber + ', ' + secondNumber + ')');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/javascript-fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-slice-vs-for-loop) for more information about the array duplication.

For usage and testing, see: http://jsfiddle.net/gycjup5u/2/

Comment: That's order n^2. And worse than the original in run time (it does length^2 comparions, like the original, but sorts as well)

Comment: Yeah, my (corrected) typo was totally worth a "-1".

Comment: That;s still n^2. So, yes, it was

Comment: No it isn't. The second iteration starts at **i+1**!

Comment: I did spot that. It doesnt make any difference, it's still O(N^2). Count'em.

Comment: (it isn't `j<i+diff`, as we can very well have `sortedInput[i+1] == sortedInput[i] + diff`, even with `diff > 1`)

Comment: That can only happen if you have duplicates. Take a (single)pass over to eliminate duplicates, then it does work.

Comment: It has nothing to do with duplicates... please read more carefully. Anyway, I think akarilimano's solution is much better.

Comment: 'sortedInput[i+1] == sortedInput[i] + diff" if you have that you have a pair. That's not a problem. The point is you have to go up to i+diff to know you've tried all elements that could be a pair (in the absence of duplicates)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm with @Paul on this - it is indeed O(n^2)

Comment: Actually , change the loop to for `(j == i+i j < n && sortedInput[j] <= sortedInput[i]+diff; j++)`. That is O(1) without duplicates and still works with.

Comment: Actually, what made in O(n^2) was the lack of a `break` statement. Fixed.

Comment: Nope (but you're close). It's O(N^2) if there are no pairs (or not pairs for every element). You need to end the loop if you've gone too far, as well as if you find a pair.

Comment: Edited with the extra condition, and changed my -1 to +1 (since your answer did give code...)

Answer (score 3):

do you have memory for a copy of the array?  Sort it first, O(n log n), then pick out the pairs in a single O(n) pass.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `indexOf()` method for every element to determine if an array contains the element greater than given by `diff`:

```
function getPossiblePairs(input, diff) {
    for(i in input) {
        var n = input.indexOf(input[i] + diff);
        if(n != -1) {
            console.log("(" + input[i] + "," + input[n] + ")");
        }
    }
}

getPossiblePairs(input, diff);
```

Comment: Which is, of course, O(N^2). So the OP will still feel guilty :)

Comment: @Paul yes, this is my fault, didn't notice the optimization request, just thought of another way of doing it.