# javascript better way to "reset" an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there any faster/better way to "reset" the array than what Im currently doing?

```
-- populate arrayA and arrayCache using for loop

-- shuffle arrayA

/* empty arrayA */
arrayA = [];  -

/* THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART, reset the array (load values from arrayCache into arrayA) */
for(i = 0; i < arrayCache.length; i++)
{
  arrayA.push(arrayCache[i]);
}
```

I populate (using loop) 2 arrays (arrayA and arrayCache), then iterate and shuffle (if condition is met) the first arrayA and then I need to reset it to its original state.

*Note - if I simply do arrayA = arrayCache, then arrayCache is changed simultaneously with arrayA*

Comment: Possible [duplicate of this posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/javascript-fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-slice-vs-for-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do, but it will change the array referenced by `arrayA`

```
-- populate arrayA and arrayCache using for loop

-- shuffle arrayA

/* empty arrayA */
arrayA = [];  -

/* THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART, reset the array (load values from arrayCache into arrayA) */
arrayA = arrayCache.slice(0)
```

If you want to modify the original array referred by `arrayA` then

```
arrayA.push.apply(arrayA, arrayCache)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this would work

```
arrayA=arrayCache.concat();
```