# In a duplicated array of strings, why does replacing text in the duplicate alter the original?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm running a psychology experiment in js. I have an array of strings and I'm replacing the text in two of these strings.The array changes depending on the input I want from my participants. So I have the original array `Array1`, which contains some placeholder values, and a duplicate array that contains the values I want participants to see `Array2`. I enter the new values using `.replace`. Weirdly (or maybe it's just my understanding of js), using `Array2[n].replace('placeholder', 'new text')` replaces the placeholder in both arrays. Here's some script that replicates the issue (in Chrome).

```
Array1 = ['rhubarb', 'placeholder', 'rhubarb', 'rhubarb']
Array2 = Array1
Array2[1] = Array2[1].replace('placeholder', 'new text')

Array1

["rhubarb", "new text", "rhubarb", "rhubarb"]
```

Using `Array2 = Array1.slice()` eliminates the issue, so I guess `Array2 = Array1` is only pointing to `Array1` rather than copying it. Why does `Array2 = Array1` allow modifications to `Array2` to travel up the chain of reference, so to speak?

I'm sure this is fairly basic, but I'm not a programmer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array in javascript is also an object. Objects are treated as references. Basically they point to the same piece of data. The logical consequence is that if you modify one, it affects the other.

If you want to create a clone (independent copy) to avoid this kind of behavior you might want to refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3978492/50158) on how to duplicate arrays. It has plenty of answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is actually, that two arrays are pointing to the same data; I mean they do not contain separate values. In order to copy values of an old array, you have better use `.slice` method. It looks like this

`Array2 = Array1.slice()
Array2[1] = Array2[1].replace('placeholder', 'new text');`