# What is the purpose of slicing a javascript array from 0 to Arrays.length?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to understand source code from ionic codePen:
http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/rxysG
The developer has used the following piece of code in his demo:

```
 $scope.messages = messageOptions.slice(0, messageOptions.length);
```

Why the developer didn't write:

```
$scope.messages = messageOptions;   //messageOptions is an array defined in the code which you can check from the codepen link that I have pasted.
```

Comment: Becouse he wanted to create copy of an array:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/javascript-fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-slice-vs-for-loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement `$scope.messages = messageOptions.slice(0, messageOptions.length);` create a clone/copy of array and assigning it to `$scope.messages`

You can also achieve same using

```
 $scope.messages = messageOptions.slice();
```

*Code to demonstrate*

```js
var messageOptions = [1, 2];
var messages = messageOptions.slice(0, messageOptions.length);

//Update 
messageOptions[0] = 100;

snippet.log("messages: " + JSON.stringify(messages));
snippet.log("messageOptions: " + JSON.stringify(messageOptions));
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For `messageOptions` may be an `array-like` object like `arguments` instead of an instance of `Array` and they probably want the latter.

Doing that assures that arrays remain arrays, while array-like objects are properly mapped on an array instance.