# not able to set dataset value in chart.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

i want to set dataset value dynamically of chart.js to create a bar graph which i am trying to do with the following code

```
getmths();
mthlen=marr.length;
xdistid=$('#mdistid').val();
mdistid=xdistid.split(',');
mdilen=mdistid.length;
var distdata=[];
for(i=0;i<mdilen;i++)
{
glc=mdistid[i];
for(j=0;j<mthlen;j++)
{
mth=marr[j];
switch(mth)
{
case '1':
distdata[j]=$('#qty1'+glc).val();
break;
case '2':
distdata[j]=$('#qty2'+glc).val();
break;
case '3':
distdata[j]=$('#qty3'+glc).val();
break;
case '4':
distdata[j]=$('#qty4'+glc).val();
break;
case '5':
distdata[j]=$('#qty5'+glc).val();
break;
case '6':
distdata[j]=$('#qty6'+glc).val();
break;
case '7':
distdata[j]=$('#qty7'+glc).val();
break;
case '8':
distdata[j]=$('#qty8'+glc).val();
break;
case '9':
distdata[j]=$('#qty9'+glc).val();
break;
case '10':
distdata[j]=$('#qty10'+glc).val();
break;
case '11':
distdata[j]=$('#qty11'+glc).val();
break;
case '12':
distdata[j]=$('#qty12'+glc).val();
break;
}

}
//Month Loop Ends here;

alert("Distributor data:"+distdata);

if(i==0)
{
datasetValue[0]=
{
label: "My Second dataset",
fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
data: distdata
};  
}
if(i==1)
{
datasetValue[1]=
{
label: "My Second dataset",
fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
data: distdata
};  
}

}
//Distributor Loop Ends here;

alert("Datasets: "+datasetValue[0].data);
alert(datasetValue.length);
mkchart();
mklinechart();
```

my problem is that after the loop finishes when i am checking the value of datasetValue[0].data i am getting the same value which sholud be of datasetValue[1].data please help me with this problem.........Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> my problem is that after the loop finishes when i am checking the
>   value of datasetValue[0].data i am getting the same value which sholud
>   be of datasetValue[1].data

Your issue is that you are setting the `data` of both chart datasets to the same array object (`distdata`). When you update the array, both dataset's `data` object change (because they 2 variables that point to the same object)

You can fix this easily by creating a copy of `distdata` when you assign it to the `data` property of the dataset. The easiest way to do this is using  `slice()` (see [Javascript fastest way to duplicate an Array - slice vs for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/javascript-fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-slice-vs-for-loop) for a more ways to do this).

In short, change your dataset assignment to be like so (notice the extra `.slice()`)

```
...
if (i == 0) {
    datasetValue[0] =
    {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: distdata.slice()
    };
}
if (i == 1) {
    datasetValue[1] =
    {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: distdata.slice()
    };
}
...
```

Comment: That's nice. Without slice at all or without slice on the 2nd one? (the 2nd slice is not actually required if you have 2 arrays - I just included it because it makes it consistent and easier to maintain)