# Iterate first x elements of an associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iterator, iteration

With an associative array of 12 elements;

```
 this.rolls = {1:[], 2:[], 3:[], 4:[], 5:[],
                6:[], 7:[], 8:[], 9:[],10:[], 11:[], 12:[]};
```

what is the most effective way to get the sum of just the first 10 elements. The code below currently sums all elements;

```
  var sum = 0;
  for (var k in this.rolls) {
    vals = this.rolls[k];
    for (var i=0; i<vals.length; i++) {
      sum += vals[i] || 0
    };
  };
  this.score = sum
```

The first 10 elements being:

```
 this.rolls = {1:[], 2:[], 3:[], 4:[], 5:[],
                    6:[], 7:[], 8:[], 9:[],10:[]};
```

Here is the full code:

```
function Game() {
  this.score = 0;
  this.frameOver = false;
  this.rolls = {1:[], 2:[], 3:[], 4:[], 5:[],
                6:[], 7:[], 8:[], 9:[],10:[], 11:[], 12:[]};
  this.currentFrame = 1;
  // this.lastFrameStrike = false;
  // this.lastFrameSpare = false;
  // this.isStrike = false
};

Game.prototype.roll = function(pins) {
  this.strikeOrSpare(pins);
  this.bonusDistributor(pins);
  this.rolls[this.currentFrame].push(pins);
  this.scoreUpdater(pins);
  this.frameHandler(pins);
  this.nextFrameBonus(pins)
};

// --------------------------------------------------

Game.prototype.strikeOrSpare = function(pins) {
  if (pins === 10) {
    this.isStrike = true;
    this.frameOver = true
  }
  else if (this.rolls[this.currentFrame][0] + pins === 10) {
    this.isSpare = true;
    this.frameOver = true
  };
};

// --------------------------------------------------

Game.prototype.bonusDistributor = function(pins) {
  if(this.wasSpare) { this.addToLastSpare(pins) };
  if(this.wasStrike) { this.addToLast(pins) };
  if(this.wasStrike2 && this.currentFrame > 1) { this.addToLastAgain(pins) };
};

// --------------------------------------------------

Game.prototype.addToLast = function(pins) {
  this.rolls[this.currentFrame - 1][0] += pins
};

Game.prototype.addToLastAgain = function(pins) {
  this.rolls[this.currentFrame - 2][0] += pins
};

Game.prototype.addToLastSpare = function(pins) {
  this.rolls[this.currentFrame - 1][1] += pins;
  this.wasSpare = false
};

// --------------------------------------------------

Game.prototype.scoreUpdater = function(pins) {
  var sum = Object.keys(this.rolls).sort(function (a, b) {
      return (+a) - (+b);
  }).slice(0, 10).reduce(function (p, c) {
      return p + this.rolls[c].reduce(function (p, c) {
          return p + c;
      }, 0);
  }, 0);
};

Game.prototype.frameHandler = function(pins) {
  if (this.frameOver) {
    this.currentFrame++; this.frameOver = !this.frameOver
  } else {
  this.frameOver = !this.frameOver;
  };
};

Game.prototype.nextFrameBonus = function(pins) {
  if (this.isSpare) {
    this.wasSpare = true;
    this.isSpare = false
    if (this.wasStrike) {
      this.wasStrike = false;
      this.wasStrike2 = true
    }
  } else if (this.isStrike && this.wasStrike) {
    this.wasStrike2 = true
  } else if (this.isStrike) {
    this.isStrike = false;
    this.wasStrike = true
  } else if (this.wasStrike) {
    this.wasStrike = false;
    this.wasStrike2 = true
  } else if (this.wasStrike2) {
    this.wasStrike2 = false
  };
};

// --------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What do you mean by first 10 elements? Can you be more specific?

Comment: `this.rolls` containing 12 elements, the sum of the first 10 is required

Comment: We are talking about an associative array (key-value pairs) Which 10 elements do you expect?

Comment: Properties order in objects are not guaranted...

Comment: @thefourtheye only sum of the values attached to the first ten keys

Comment: There is no `first 10` in an object literal which is what you have. Either need proper array or define criteria for property keys needed

Comment: I understand this, I mean keys 1...10 inclusive, see edit

Comment: check my answer, if you have any problem let me know

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev @Jacob @charlietfl - all of your solution work on jsfiddle, however in my local I'm getting back `Cannot read property '1' of undefined` - apologies I'm new

Comment: can you give me value of `this.rolls`?

Comment: Okay yes, to begin with this is the array:
`rolls = {1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: [],
    6: [], 7: [], 8: [8, 9, 10], 9: [], 10: [], 11: [], 12: []};`

Comment: so my tests fail because the code is trying to sum null values - please see full codebase above - `Game.prototype.scoreUpdater` does work but **only** when `this.rolls` is full, it need to get the total up to this.rolls[10] even when partially empty

Comment: @Stussy. I have found your issue. Check my answer again. It has fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:** There is one mistake in your example. You cannot use **this**.*rolls* inside of `forEach`. Declare it (`var self = this;` or my version is `var rolls = this.rolls;` outside)

I suggest following code for calculating sum:

```
var sum = 0;
var rolls = this.rolls;
Object.keys(rolls).forEach(function (key, i, array) {
    if (i < 10) {
        var item = rolls[key].slice();
        while (item.length) {
            sum += item ? Number(item.shift()) : 0 + item ? Number(item.pop()) : 0;
        }
    }
});
console.log(sum, this.rolls);
this.score = sum;
```

There is your full example:

```js
function Game() {
    this.score = 0;
    this.frameOver = false;
    this.rolls = {1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: [], 6: [], 7: [], 8: [], 9: [], 10: [], 11: [], 12: []};
    this.currentFrame = 1;
    // this.lastFrameStrike = false;
    // this.lastFrameSpare = false;
    // this.isStrike = false
}

Game.prototype.roll = function (pins) {
    this.strikeOrSpare(pins);
    this.bonusDistributor(pins);
    this.rolls[this.currentFrame].push(pins);
    this.scoreUpdater(pins);
    this.frameHandler(pins);
    this.nextFrameBonus(pins);
};

// --------------------------------------------------

Game.prototype.strikeOrSpare = function (pins) {
    if (pins === 10) {
        this.isStrike = true;
        this.frameOver = true;
    }
    else if (this.rolls[this.currentFrame][0] + pins === 10) {
        this.isSpare = true;
        this.frameOver = true;
    }
};

// --------------------------------------------------

Game.prototype.bonusDistributor = function (pins) {
    if (this.wasSpare) {
        this.addToLastSpare(pins);
    }
    if (this.wasStrike) {
        this.addToLast(pins);
    }
    if (this.wasStrike2 && this.currentFrame > 1) {
        this.addToLastAgain(pins);
    }
};

// --------------------------------------------------

Game.prototype.addToLast = function (pins) {
    this.rolls[this.currentFrame - 1][0] += pins;
};

Game.prototype.addToLastAgain = function (pins) {
    this.rolls[this.currentFrame - 2][0] += pins;
};

Game.prototype.addToLastSpare = function (pins) {
    this.rolls[this.currentFrame - 1][1] += pins;
    this.wasSpare = false;
};

// --------------------------------------------------

Game.prototype.scoreUpdater = function (pins) {
    var sum = 0;
//    var self = this;
    var rolls = this.rolls;
    Object.keys(rolls).forEach(function (key, i, array) {
        if (i < 10) {
            var item = rolls[key].slice();
            while (item.length) {
                sum += item ? Number(item.shift()) : 0 + item ? Number(item.pop()) : 0;
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(sum, this.rolls);
    this.score = sum;
};

Game.prototype.frameHandler = function (pins) {
    if (this.frameOver) {
        this.currentFrame++;
        this.frameOver = !this.frameOver;
    } else {
        this.frameOver = !this.frameOver;
    }
};

Game.prototype.nextFrameBonus = function (pins) {
    if (this.isSpare) {
        this.wasSpare = true;
        this.isSpare = false;
        if (this.wasStrike) {
            this.wasStrike = false;
            this.wasStrike2 = true;
        }
    } else if (this.isStrike && this.wasStrike) {
        this.wasStrike2 = true;
    } else if (this.isStrike) {
        this.isStrike = false;
        this.wasStrike = true;
    } else if (this.wasStrike) {
        this.wasStrike = false;
        this.wasStrike2 = true;
    } else if (this.wasStrike2) {
        this.wasStrike2 = false;
    }
};
var game = new Game();
game.scoreUpdater();
```

Comment: So, You should remove your downvote, now, my answer is correct

Comment: `.slice(0)` is faster than `.slice()` or others for cloning array. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21514254/4365315

Comment: Thanks Sherali, btw it wasn't me who downvoted, your response was helpful

Answer (score 3):

The first issue you'll have problems with is that `this.rolls` is an `Object`, not an `Array`, so `for (var k in this.rolls)` is not *guaranteed* to enumerate the keys in order. So the first problem to solve is to take those first 10 keys, convert them to numbers, and sort them. Here I'm using all native `Array` and `Object` methods:

```
var rolls = this.rolls;
var sum = Object
  // Get all keys
  .keys(rolls)
  // Convert string keys to integers
  .map(function (key) { return parseInt(key, 10); })
  // Sort in ascending order
  .sort()
  // Take the first 10
  .slice(0, 10)
  // Get the arrays for each key
  .map(function (key) { return rolls[key]; })
  // Merge all arrays into one array
  .reduce(function (allNumbers, array) { return allNumbers.concat(array); }, [])
  // Sum all numbers
  .reduce(function (sum, number) { return sum + (number || 0); }, 0);
```

Comment: you cannot use `this.rolls` inside of `map()`

Comment: Yep, am used to using arrow functions usually. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sort and filter object keys, then use them to reduce arrays to sums

```
var rolls = this.rolls;
var sum = Object.keys(rolls).sort(function (a, b) {
    return (+a) - (+b);
}).slice(0, 10).reduce(function (p, c) {
    return p + rolls[c].reduce(function (p, c) {
        return p + c;
    }, 0);
}, 0);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/z37qjmyc/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: you cannot use `this.rolls` inside of `reduce()`

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev minor over site ..thx. Not sure why it merits a downvote, demo version works fine