# Copy an array without linking to it

Tags: javascript, arrays, copy

```
var ProtVar = function(arr){
    this.gr1 = [];
    this.gr2 = [];
    this.arr = arr;
    return this;
}
ProtVar.prototype.setArrs = function(){
    this.gr1 = this.arr;
    this.gr2 = this.arr;
    return this;
}
ProtVar.prototype.shiftGr1 = function(){
    this.gr1.shift();
    return this;
}
ProtVar.prototype.showData = function(){
    console.log("gr1 = ", this.gr1.length, this.gr1);
    console.log("gr2 = ", this.gr2.length, this.gr2);
    console.log("arr = ", this.arr.length, this.arr);    
    return this;   
}
var protVar = new ProtVar([1,2,3,4]).setArrs().shiftGr1().showData();
```

How should I copy the array without linking to the same array?

I figured out how to do this with `slice(0);` see below.

```
ProtVar.prototype.setArrs = function(){
    this.gr1 = this.arr.slice(0);
    this.gr2 = this.arr.slice(0);
    return this;
}
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: In this case (array of primitives) it is one viable way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are at least 4 (!) principal ways to clone an array:
>
> - loop
> - constructor
> - slice / splice
> - concat

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20547803/4185234) answer

Comment: thanks, sorry for duplicate question :/