# Replace element at specific position in an array without mutating it

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, immutability

How can the following operation be done without mutating the array:

```
let array = ['item1'];
console.log(array); // ['item1']
array[2] = 'item2'; // array is mutated
console.log(array); // ['item1', undefined, 'item2']
```

In the above code, `array` variable is mutated. How can I perform the same operation without mutating the array?

Comment: If you want something **fast** https://stackoverflow.com/a/47943825/1480391 ,;)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You can use [`Object.assign(target, source1, source2, /* …, */ sourceN)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
Object.assign([], array, {2: newItem});
```

Comment: @DanPrince Not sure about how these sharing structures are implemented. But slice copies the full array so that case is also O(n).

Comment: Any documentation on `Object.assign`?

Comment: That said, copying an array with `slice` might be faster because `length` is copied first, so preallocation is possible. `Object.assign(array.slice(), {2: newItem});` is another possibility.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon See `Object.assign` in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.assign)

Comment: Not sure if this is a one-off fix in a program the original poster is writing or the end result will be a application accessed across multiple devices and browsers but... there is no support for `internet explorer` or `android`.  You may want to add a disclaimer in your answer and reference a polyfill perhaps.

Comment: @cemper93 It can work, you just need to use this specific syntax: 
`Object.assign([], array, { [i]: newItem })`

Comment: This will replace the item if it contains a previously existing item in the array.

`Object.assign([], [1,2,3,4], {2: 5}); ===> [1, 2, 5, 4]`

Comment: Not sure but this might be very bad for engines performance optimization when assigning to indexes that are >= than arrays length?

Answer (score 19):

## The **fast** way

```
function replaceAt(array, index, value) {
  const ret = array.slice(0);
  ret[index] = value;
  return ret;
}
```

See the [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/copy-array-object-assign-vs-array-from-vs-array-slice) (thanks to [@Bless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1421222/bless))

Related posts:

- [Javascript fastest way to duplicate an Array - slice vs for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3978492/1480391)
- https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2053#issuecomment-188776090

Comment: Yes. +1. Here is a perf comparison - https://jsperf.com/copy-array-object-assign-vs-array-from-vs-array-slice

Answer (score 14):

You can simply set up a new array as such:

```
const newItemArray = array.slice();
```

And then set value for the index which you wish to have a value for.

```
newItemArray[position] = newItem
```

and return that. The values under the indexes in-between will have `undefined`.

Or the obviously alternative would be:

```
Object.assign([], array, {<position_here>: newItem});
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is how I'd like to do it:

```
function update(array, newItem, atIndex) {
    return array.map((item, index) => index === atIndex ? newItem : item);
}
```

Generally, Array-spread operation produces few temporary arrays for you, but `map` doesn't, so it can be faster. You can also look at [this discussion](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/pull/1468) as a reference

Comment: Nice but the redux discussion is about removing an element, I think the fastest way to replace an element is https://stackoverflow.com/a/47943825/1480391 ;)

Answer (score 7):

Well, technically this wouldn't be *replacing* as there isn't an item at the index you're changing.

Look at how it's handled in Clojure—a language that's built around canonical implementations for immutable data structures.

```
(assoc [1] 2 3)
;; IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Not only does it fail, but it crashes too. These data structures are designed to be as robust as possible and when you come up against these kinds of errors, it's generally not because you've discovered an edge case, but more likely that you're using the wrong data structure.

If you are ending up with sparse arrays, then consider modelling them with objects or maps instead.

```
let items = { 0: 1 };
{ ...items, 2: 3 };
// => { 0: 1, 2: 3 }

let items = new Map([ [0, 1] ]);
items(2, 3);
// => Map {0 => 1, 2 => 3}
```

However, Map is a fundamentally mutable data structure, so you'd need to swap this out for an immutable variant with a library like [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) or [Mori](http://swannodette.github.io/mori/).

```
let items = Immutable.Map([ [0, 2] ]);
items.set(2, 3);
// => Immutable.Map {0 => 1, 2 => 3}

let items = mori.hashMap();
mori.assoc(items, 2, 3);
// => mori.hashMap {0 => 1, 2 => 3}
```

Of course, there might be a perfectly good reason for wanting to use JavaScript's arrays, so here's a solution for good measure.

```
function set(arr, index, val) {
  if(index < arr.length) {
    return [
      ...arr.slice(0, position),
      val,
      ...arr.slice(position + 1)
    ];
  } else {
    return [
      ...arr,
      ...Array(index - arr.length),
      val
    ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way could be to use spread operator with slice as

```js
let newVal = 33, position = 3;
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
let newArr = [...arr.slice(0,position - 1), newVal, ...arr.slice(position)];
console.log(newArr); //logs [1, 2, 33, 4, 5]
console.log(arr); //logs [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Note that `position` in this snippet is not zero based. If you have a zero based index, it is `[...arr.slice(0, index), newVal, ...arr.slice(index + 1)]`

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```js
const newArray = [...array]; // make a copy of the original array
newArray[2] = 'item2'; // mutate the copy
```

I find the intent a bit more clear than this one-liner:

```js
const newArray = Object.assign([...array], {2: 'item2'});
```

Comment: I love the latter form, it really reads well!

Answer (score 3):

There's a new [tc39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-change-array-by-copy), which adds a `with` method to `Array` that returns a copy of the array and doesn't modify the original:

```js
Array.prototype.with(index, value) -> Array
```

Example from the proposal:

```js
const correctionNeeded = [1, 1, 3];
correctionNeeded.with(1, 2); // => [1, 2, 3]
correctionNeeded; // => [1, 1, 3]
```

(note that a `RangeError` will be thrown if the first argument to `with` is outside the bounds of the array, so the specific example in the question will not work)

As it's currently in stage 3, it will likely be implemented in browser engines soon, but in the meantime a polyfill is available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array.prototype.with) or in [`core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#change-array-by-copy).

Answer (score 2):

```js
var list1 = ['a','b','c'];
var list2 = list1.slice();
list2.splice(2, 0, "beta", "gamma");
console.log(list1);
console.log(list2);
```

Is this what you want?