# update the state of an object who's values are an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, state

I'm looking for a way to update a single index of an object's values that are an array while saving the state of the other values. I tried using a spread operator, but I'm getting an error.

```
const [points, setPoints] = useState({"x": [46, 168, 292, 415, 537, 660] , "y":[60, 192, 324, 454]});

const update = (e) => {
    setPoints(points => ({
      ...points,
      x[0]: e
    }));
  };
```

I am unsure how to update the specific index.

Thanks!

Comment: this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673783/replace-array-entry-with-spread-syntax-in-one-line-of-code

Comment: might help too https://stackoverflow.com/a/38061256/13583510

Answer (score 1):

#### Be more focussed in your update

Build up the new value of the object from the parts of the old object. Remember that `x` and `y` are independent properties of that object. So you can simply let `y` flow through unchanged, but need to build a new `x`.

A simple way of building the new `x` is creating a new array, starting with `e`, and then taking all remaining items of the old `x`, starting from item #1 (i.e. omitting #0).

I've made the function name more clearly indicate you are only updating `x[0]`.

```
const [points, setPoints] = useState({"x": [46, 168, 292, 415, 537, 660] , "y":[60, 192, 324, 454]});

const updateX0 = (e) => {
    setPoints(points => ({
      x:[e, points.x.slice(1)],
      y: points.y
    }));
  };
```