# Fill an array in javascript inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i'm new to javascript and i have a little issue. I have an array like this:

```
name = ["Alex","John", "Mark"].
```

After that, i have and object with an array inside like this:

```
ObjectNames = {
  labels: []
}
```

I want to fill the labels array with the content of tha name array like this:

```
labels = [name[0], name[1], name[2]]
```

How to do this?

Comment: You already did that.

Comment: Just do ObjectNames.labels = name;

Comment: What you show works. You could also just have used `labels : name` inside the object unless you want to clone everything.

Comment: Do `labels: [...name]`

Comment: `ObjectNames.labels = name.slice();`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript fastest way to duplicate an Array - slice vs for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/javascript-fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-slice-vs-for-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did in your question already solves your problem, but you can try this:

```
ObjectNames = {
    labels: names
}
```

This will make a copy of names and store it in labels.

Let me know if it works

**Edit:** As Andrew Li pointed out, there's no need to use slice, as JavaScript automatically creates a copy

Comment: Or just `slice()`. No argument required

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I just realized that, thanks for clarifying. I've never been sure about when Javascript makes a copy and when it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this :

```js
var _name = ["Alex","John", "Mark"];
var ObjectNames = {
  labels: []
};
_name.forEach(function(e) {
  ObjectNames.labels.push(e);
});
console.log(ObjectNames.labels);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of way you can do that

Try like this

```
var ObjectNames = {
  labels: [name[0], name[1], name[2]]
}
```

or

```
var ObjectNames = {
  labels: name
}
```

or

```
var ObjectNames = {
  labels: name.slice()
}
```

or

```
ObjectNames = {
  labels: []
}

ObjectNames.labels=name ;
```

or like this

```
for(var i=0;i<name.length;i++)
  ObjectNames.labels.push(name[i])
```

or

```
name.forEach(x=> ObjectNames.labels.push(x))
```

Comment: i want to do this with a for loop not like that