# React setState updates props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, multi-select, setstate

I am working on a component that includes multiple sub components that can be selected (or 'activated', as the naming here says.). I have an array of IDs which should be initialised with all IDs being selected, so `this.state.activeSensors` refers to the total list of sensors: `this.props.mainViewSensors`. 
The functions `sensorSelect` gets the ID, and should by this be able to determine if it is selected or not. My approach has been to check if it is in the activeSensors list- Remove it if it's there, add it if it's not. Set the new state.

When I remove an item from the new list `newActiveSensors` and call the setState, the clicked item somehow disappears  from the props as well. I did not know that this was possible. Is it something I have done wrong?

Here is what I did:

```
const propTypes = {
  mainViewSensors: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
};

const defaultProps = {
    mainViewSensors: [
        '21EL',
        '05LO',
        '08HT',
        '81EL',
        '05TF',
    ],
}

class Multiselect extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.sensorSelect = this.sensorSelect.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            activeSensors: this.props.mainViewSensors,
            selectedSensors: this.props.mainViewSensors,
        };
    }

  sensorSelect(sensor) {
    const newActiveSensors = this.state.activeSensors;
    if (newActiveSensors.includes(sensor)) {
        const index = newActiveSensors.indexOf(sensor);
        newActiveSensors.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        newActiveSensors.push(sensor);
    }
    this.setState({
        activeSensors: newActiveSensors,
    });
  }

    render() {
    const { selectedSensors, activeSensors } = this.state;

    return (
    <div className="wrapper">
        {this.state.selectedSensors.map((tag) => (
            <div key={tag} role="button" className="main-gauge-holder" onClick={this.sensorSelect(tag)}>
                <MainGauge tag={tag} />
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
    );
  }
}

Multiselect.propTypes = propTypes;
Multiselect.defaultProps = defaultProps;

React.render(<Multiselect />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Just to make it clear, I'm making something like this, where the green arrow show which one is selected (here I have manually changed the active state in child component): 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not a React problem, your just using the same instance of the array over you class. You have to [make a new array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/javascript-fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-slice-vs-for-loop) in order to use a copy of it.

See my example for clarification :

```js
var primaryArray = [1, 2, 3];

console.log('Init :');
console.log(primaryArray);

var obj = {
  array: primaryArray, // Same instance
  clonedArray: primaryArray.slice() // Clone
};

console.log(obj);

console.log('Poping from the same instance :');
obj.array.pop();

console.log(obj);
console.log(primaryArray);

console.log('Poping from the cloned array doesn\'t affect primary one :');
obj.clonedArray.pop();

console.log(obj);
console.log(primaryArray);
```

Comment: Oh my, this worked like a charm! I thought that the const in the beginning of the function did make a copy, and I didn't think more of it as all my attention went to the props change.. Thank you so much!