# How to push a value but not a reference

Tags: javascript

I want to push an array in the other array.I know concat() but what i want is not this. 
 **Two dimensional array** 
perhaps:

```
    var a = [],b = [],c = [];
a.push(1);
b.push(a);
console.log(b);      //[[1]]
a.push(2);
console.log(b)       //[[1,2]]
a.push(3);           
console.log(b)       //[[1,2,3]]
```

b will be changed if a is changed,what i want is

```
 var a = [],b = [],c = [];
a.push(1);
b.push(a);
console.log(b)       //[[1]]
a.push(2);
console.log(b)       //[[1]]
a.push(3);           
console.log(b)       //[[1]]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to more clearly explain your desired result. What should `b` look like after the code runs? Are you saying you *don't* want a two-dimensional array?

Comment: how to push a value but not a reference

Comment: Using `.push`?.

Comment: You're not being clear at all, but I suspect you want `b.push(a.slice())`, it's still a reference of a value, but you'd get a copy of the array instead of the original.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/javascript-fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-slice-vs-for-loop

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: I don't understand your use case. If you don't want the value to appear under `b` then just add a guard statement to preven it been added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could point to a two dimension array like `b[1][0]`.

you could use the following code to push an array values into another array

```
b.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Comment: yes , this is the correct,this is what i want, thank you

Answer (score 0):

To append array `a` onto array `b`, you can simply concatenate your arrays `a` and `b` together, as follows,

```
var a = a.concat(b);
```

or

```
var a = [].concat(a,b);
```

Both of these examples will return a combined array with all elements from both `a` and `b`.

Comment: Wouldn't `= a.concat(b)` do the same thing more concisely?

Comment: Yes, but a lot of time someone may forget that you have to assign the results back to `a`. I'll update my answer.