# How to add object inside array without reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

**My code is so far**

```
var chartSeriesArray = [{"EnableAnimation": true,"AnimationDuration": 1}];

let refArray = chartSeriesArray; 
let clonedArray = [...chartSeriesArray]; // will clone the array

var x = [];
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    x.push(clonedArray);
}   
x[0].foo = "bar";
console.log(x);
```

**Console Output is**

```
0:[{…}, foo: "bar"]
1:[{…}, foo: "bar"]
```

Whether I am trying to loop `refArray` or `clonedArray` in both the cases, it's added foo in both item `0` and `1`, i want to add only in `0` for example.

**Expected output is**

```
0:[{…}, foo: "bar"]
1:[{…}]
```

I want to access `0` and `1` individually later.

I tried everything but nothing works, Any help is highly appreciated.

**Further after all suggestions, when i am trying below code**

```
var metadata = 
{
    "KPISDetail": [{
        "ChartSeriesList": {
            "EnableAnimation": true,
            "AnimationDuration": 1
        }
    }, {
        "ChartSeriesList": {
            "EnableAnimation": true,
            "AnimationDuration": 1
        }
    }]
}

var data = [];
var x = [];

for(var l=0;l<2;l++){
    data.push(metadata.KPISDetail[l].ChartSeriesList);
    x.push(...data.map(o => Object.assign({}, o)))
}
x[0].foo = "bar";
x[1].foo = "foo";
console.log(x);
```

**Result should be 2 only because my loop is executing 2 times. But i am getting output 3 times, which is wrong. I am getting below output**

[image]

Comment: Hint: Why did you clone `chartSeriesArray`?

Comment: You are just pushing the same array again and again... you should [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21514254/1151408) it inside the loop

Comment: The important part is to understand that while the spread operator does clone the array, it does not clone the objects inside the array. So you end up with a _new_ array containing _references_ to the objects in the _old_ array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing clonedArray into x 2 time but you forgot about both time you are using same variable so memory allocation of both are same so if you want to add something on x element they reflect on both. To achieve desire result that you can use like that -

```
var chartSeriesArray = [{"EnableAnimation": true,"AnimationDuration": 1}];

let refArray = chartSeriesArray; 
let clonedArray = [...chartSeriesArray]; // will clone the array

var x = [];
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    x.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(clonedArray))); // will create magic 
}   
x[0].foo = "bar";
console.log(x);
```

Updated Code -

```
var metadata = 
{
    "KPISDetail": [{
        "ChartSeriesList": {
            "EnableAnimation": true,
            "AnimationDuration": 1
        }
    }, {
        "ChartSeriesList": {
            "EnableAnimation": true,
            "AnimationDuration": 1
        }
    }]
}

var data = [];
var x = [];

for(var l=0;l<2;l++){
    x.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(metadata.KPISDetail[1].ChartSeriesList)))
}
x[0].foo = "bar";
x[1].foo = "foo";
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create array clone with cloned elements:

```
let clonedArray = chartSeriesArray.map((item) => Object.assign({}, item))
```

Comment: @Yuri You are responding to the OP. This answer does exactly what you are describing.

Comment: A part from jQuery being used here, it doesn't match very much with OP code, but clonedArray will contain the desired output. (Removing my previous comment)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following:

```
var x = [];
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    let real_clone = clonedArray.slice(0); // if you need to clone an array
    let real_clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(clonedArray)); // if you need to clone both array and object
    x.push(real_clone);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is you create a single cloned array and pushed in multiple time. You need to create a new cloned array for every single push.

```js
var chartSeriesArray = [{"EnableAnimation":true,"AnimationDuration": 1}];
var x = [];
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    x.push([...chartSeriesArray]);
}   
x[0].foo = "bar";
console.log(x);
```