# Javascript: Copy Array with filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, copy, array-filter

As I understood there is no best practice for copying an Array in Javascript.

Would it be a could idea to use Array.filter, to copy an Array?

Something like:

```
var words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];
const result = words.filter(word => word);
```

Because filter returns a new Array?
Are there any disatvantages using this Method?

Comment: if you want a copy of the original array with only words whose length are greater than 6, then yes, that is the best way of doing it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript fastest way to duplicate an Array - slice vs for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/javascript-fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-slice-vs-for-loop)

Comment: but slice vs loop is irrelevant when you filter @Colin

Comment: sorry I edited the filter function, no length restriction

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, you are looking for something like this:

```js
var words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

var wordsCopy = Array.from(words);

console.log(wordsCopy);
```