# Why does a array get reversed even when it's not assigned using a array sort method?

Tags: javascript

Given the following situation:

```js
let ary = [1, 2, 3];

console.dir(ary);
// ^ this console.dir outputs the reversed order, even though ary is not defined using a sort
// 3, 2, 1

function x(ary) {
  let ary2 = ary.sort( function(a,b) { return b-a } );
  // only define ary2 as the sorted array
  return ary2;  
}

document.getElementById('locationAry2').innerHTML = x(ary);
// ^ this is correct since ary2 is reversed in function x
```

```html
<p id="locationAry2"></p>
```

Why does it return the array in the variable 'ary' sorted, when only the ary2 is sorted?

Comment: you say in a comment `this is correct` - except that line will never work, since `ary2` is undefined

Comment: Aha, that JSON parse works indeed. But how come that if you'd remove function x, it does show the array in the correct order?

Comment: you're right, that was of a test. I've fixed the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.prototype.sort` modifies the original array. You would need to clone `ary` into `ary2` and then sort `ary2`.

Comment: I understand. Do you have more information regarding the cloning of objects? Using the [new object method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties#Objects_and_properties) based on this the first array (ary)?

Comment: Sure, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20547803/1309907