# snapshot of a variable javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to keep a record array of a certain variable, but whenever I push that variable it doesn't push an instance of that variable, but the variable itself.

```
var array = [0,0,0];
var record = [];

record.push(array);
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    array[i]++;
}
record.push(array);
console.log(record);
//I need record to be [[0,0,0],[1,1,1]], but it gives two copies of the latter
```

Comment: You need to copy the array into a new temporary one.

Comment: It's not pushing the variable. It's pushing the array that the variable references. You only created two arrays in your code and one of them is `record`. If you want each row of record to be another array you need to create an array for every row. You could do that by copying `array` (with `array.slice(0)` for example), or by using another array literal in your loop and then filling it with the correct values.

Comment: Thanks, the slice function seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "slice" on the array (with optional "0" as first argument) to get a clone of it:

```
var array = [0,0,0];
var record = [];

record.push(array.slice(0));

for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    array[i]++;
}

record.push(array.slice(0));

console.log(record);
// record is: [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Just `.slice()` works (and is the most common usage), no need for `.slice(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a built-in function to do that:

```
var record = array.slice(0);
```

**ref:** https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone-array

Answer (score 0):

## Clone an Array

`Array.slice` is a more expensive operation ([see this method comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-in-javascript-slice-vs-for-loop/52929821#52929821)).
 Instead, you can do something like so:

```
const array = [0,0,0];
const record = [Object.values(array)];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i]++;
}

record.push(array);

console.log(record);
```

**UPDATE**:
In order to make a copy of an array, there are many options that I can think of:

```
1) [...arr]
2) [].concat(arr);
3) arr.slice();
4) arr.map(i => i);
5) Array.of(...arr);
6) Object.values(arr);
7) Object.assign([], arr);
8) JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
etc...
```