# Modify a variable locally but not globally

Tags: javascript, global-variables, local-variables

I need to save a copy of a globally set array variable, while I'm modifying it locally.  For some reason the code below doesnt seem to do this.

```
var tileArray;
        .
        .
        .
function simplify (tiles){

    tileArray = tiles;  //tileArray is the global variable passed to simplify()
    for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++){
      if (tiles[i].numeratorDim == ""){tiles[i].numeratorDim = 1};
      if (tiles[i].denominatorDim == ""){tiles[i].denominatorDim = 1};
    };
    while (thereIsAMatch(tiles)){ // a bunch of code modifying tiles, but not tileArray
        for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++){
            for (var j = 0; j < tiles.length; j ++) {
                if (unitsMatch(tiles[i].numeratorUnit, tiles[j].denominatorUnit)) {
                    tiles[i].numeratorDim = parseInt(tiles[i].numeratorDim) - 1; 
                    if (tiles[i].numeratorDim == 0){tiles[i].numeratorUnit = ""}
                        tiles[j].denominatorDim = parseInt(tiles[j].denominatorDim) - 1;
                    if (tiles[j].denominatorDim == 0){tiles[j].denominatorUnit = ""}
                  } // if unitsMatch
              } // for j
          } //for i
        } //while thereIsAMatch
    console.log(tileArray === tiles);  //returns TRUE!! But tileArray hasnt been modified!!

    return tiles;
} // function simplify
```

Comment: wrong way around try `let tiles = tileArray;`

Comment: @PaulThomas doesn't really matter as assigning an array reference to a variable does not make a copy of the array.

Comment: `let tiles = [...tileArray]`

Comment: `while, for, for, if, if` <-- This screams poor design and is definitely an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Pointy totally sorry `let tiles = tileArray.slice()`

Comment: actually, since it's an array of objects, you probably want to clone each object: `let tiles = tileArray.map(({...props}) => ({...props}))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a deep copy on this array because right now tiles and tileArray are pointing to the same piece of memory (reference). You can do this with tileArray = Arrays.from(tiles)

Here's a helpful article: https://medium.com/@gamshan001/javascript-deep-copy-for-array-and-object-97e3d4bc401a

Comment: `Array.from()` does not disjoin the values, as noted on that link.

Comment: Array.from() did not achieve the deep copy i needed, but you definitely pointed me in the right direction!  Thanks!      I ended up making new Tile objects in a for loop and populating its methods and properties one-at-a time.    (I'm sure there are *way* more elegant ways to do this, but I am just a hobbiest trying to get my program to work, by hook or by crook,)  Anyway - really appreciate your willingness to help!

Comment: Not a problem! :)

Answer (score -1):

Basically, tileArray refers to the same array, instead of creating a copy for that,

Use :

```
tileArray = tiles.slice()
```

slice(), operation clones the array and returns the reference

Comment: This only disjoins the array references.  It does not disjoin the array values themselves.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-in-javascript-slice-vs-for-loop)

To clone an array try something like:

```
var dup_array = original_array.slice();
```

But note what they say about it being a shallow copy.