# Merge two arrays in "snake" order

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm confused with the solution to this task. I have two arrays:

```
const arr1 = [ 1,   2,   3,   4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

What do I want to get after merging these arrays:

```
[1, 'a', 'b', 2, 3, 'c', 'd', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
```

Graphically it looks like a snake

[image]

It has to work also in the case when the length of the first array is shorter than the second one. For example, I have two arrays:

```
const arr1 = [ 1,   2,   3,   4];
const arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
```

And I want to get after merging:

```
[1, 'a', 'b', 2, 3, 'c', 'd', 4, 'e', 'f', 'g'];
```

[image: (image)]

Comment: what is your criteria for merging?

Comment: Would you post your code, please?

Comment: What is the logic used for the positions in the result?

Comment: Except for the `1` at the beginning, it looks like you just take 2 elements at a time from each array, until you run out. Is that correct?

Comment: Merging can happen by checking if the element index is even or odd, then picking (array1, array2) or (array2, array1) based on that. I'll stop here because the task looks a lot like a student assignment, which I don't want to solve completely. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function reorderArrays(array1, array2){
  let newArray = [];
  
  while(array1.length || array2.length) {
      array1.length && newArray.push(array1.shift());
      array2.length && newArray.push(array2.shift());
      array2.length && newArray.push(array2.shift());
      array1.length && newArray.push(array1.shift());
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(reorderArrays([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']));
console.log(reorderArrays([ 1,   2,   3,   4], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']));
```

There is room for optimization (for instance, if !length of one array, just push the rest of the other array to your new array)

This solution works for undefined edge cases.

Comment: I like this method except that it destroys the original arrays, which is a very unexpected side effect. Also, you can just get rid of the initial `array1` push by moving it into the `while` loop and ordering it as `array1`, `array2`, `array2`, `array1`.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I edited, for the destroying, you could just copy the arrays in the function

Comment: Actually you are right, cloning arrays is not this straightforward in js. If the author wants to keep original arrays, there is this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-in-javascript-slice-vs-for-loop

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly and looks beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short and immutable way to do it:

```js
const snake = (a, b) => Array.from( // create an array
    { length: Math.max(a.length, b.length) }, // as long as the longest of a and b
    (_, i) => i % 2 ? [b[i], a[i]] : [a[i], b[i]] // fill it with alternating pairs from a and b
  ).flat().filter(x => x !== undefined); // then flatten the pairs and remove undefined entries

console.log(...snake([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']));
console.log(...snake([1, 2, 3, 4], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']));
console.log(...snake([1, 2, 4, 5], []));
console.log(...snake([], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']));
```

The steps are:

1. Create an array as long as your longest array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
2. Fill it with your first array, if it is shorter, the rest will be padded with `undefined`
3. Use the second argument of `Array.from()` or use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the entries into pairs taken from both arrays, alternate the order of the pairs by checking if the index is even or odd
4. Flatten the result using [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
5. Filter-out the `undefined` using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution using [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const merge = (arr1, arr2) => {
  return arr1.flatMap((x, i) => {
    const items = [x];
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      if (i < arr2.length) {
        items.push(arr2[i]);
      }
      if (i + 1 < arr2.length) {
        items.push(arr2[i + 1]);
      }
    }
    if (i + 1 === arr1.length) {
      items.push(...arr2.slice(i + 1));
    }
    return items;
  });
}

console.log(merge([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']));    // [1, "a", "b", 2, 3, "c", "d", 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

console.log(merge([1, 2, 3, 4], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])); // [1, "a", "b", 2, 3, "c", "d", 4, "e", "f", "g"]
```

Explanation:

The function that you pass to `flatMap` will return a array of elements to include in the result array in order. The array is determined by looping over `flatMap` in the following way:

1. Each element is directly included in the result (`[x]`)
2. For each even numbered index (`i % 2 === 0`), insert up to two elements from `arr2` (`.push(arr2[i])`, `.push(arr2[i + 1])`).
3. If you're at the end of `arr1` (`i + 1 === arr1.length`), insert all the remaining items from `arr2` (`.push(...arr2.slice(i + 1))`)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a recursive approach based on this understanding of what you want:

> Form first array: take 1 item, then 2 items, then 1 item, then 2 items and so on. From the second array take always 2 items.

To generalize, the method will receive two extra arrays that will determine the cycle of elements to take from each array you want to merge:

```js
const customMerge = (a, b, toTakeA=[1], toTakeB=[1], res=[], i=0, j=0) =>
{
    if (!a.length)
        return res.concat(b);
    else if (!b.length)
        return res.concat(a);

    return customMerge(
        a.slice(toTakeA[i]),
        b.slice(toTakeB[j]),
        toTakeA,
        toTakeB,
        res.concat(a.slice(0, toTakeA[i])).concat(b.slice(0, toTakeB[j])),
        i >= toTakeA.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1,
        j >= toTakeB.length - 1 ? 0 : j + 1
    );
}

console.log("First OP merge: ", customMerge(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    [1, 2],
    [2]
));

console.log("Second OP merge: ", customMerge(
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    [1, 2],
    [2]
));

// Another custom merge.
console.log("A custom merge: ", customMerge(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    [1, 1, 2],
    [2, 1]
));

// Simple merge, 1 and 1.
console.log("Single 1 and 1 merge: ", customMerge(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

The approach mostly uses [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [Array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) in case you need to read documentation about they.

Answer (score 0):

You could take an offset and the extra element of the first array first and then take always two elements from both arrays. This apporach does not mutate the original arrays.

```js
function getSnaked(a, b) {
    var result = [],
        l = Math.min(a.length, b.length),
        i = 0;

    result.push(...a.slice(0, 1));
    while (i < l) {
        result.push(...b.slice(i, ++i + 1));
        result.push(...a.slice(i, ++i + 1));
    }
    result.push(...b.slice(i));
    result.push(...a.slice(i + 1));
    return result;
}

console.log(...getSnaked([1, 2, 3, 4], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']));
console.log(...getSnaked([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], ['a', 'b', 'c']));
console.log(...getSnaked([1, 2, 3, 4], []));
console.log(...getSnaked([], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']));
```