# Genetic Algorithm Function JS 2D arrays

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to do a basic Genetic algorithm, one of the steps is to generate the next population trough genetic crossing at n points, I have chosen arbitrarily 4. The problem is that my code runs indefinitely unless I stop it. I thought this would only generate 3 offspring. Can anyone tell me why it's being recursive?

```
let population = [
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
]


kidsFactory()

function kidsFactory() {
    let newKid = []
    let parents = population
    for(i=0; i<(parents.length - 1);i++){
        parent1 = parents[i]
        parent2 = parents[i+1]
        console.log('parent1 '+parent1);
        console.log('parent2 '+parent2);
        newKid.push(parent1[0], parent1[1], parent2[2], parent2[3], parent1[4], parent1[5], parent2[6], parent2[7], parent1[8], parent1[9])
        console.log(newKid);
        population.push(newKid)
        newKid=[]
        console.log(population);
    }
}
```

Comment: `let parents = population` does not create a new array. Both varibales point to the same array and you are incresing it's length in every iteration `population.push(newKid)`

Comment: Oh that's my mistake, why does it not create a new array ? and how do I duplicate an array under a different name ?

Comment: @DavidRomero You can use spread syntax to create a shallow copy, as shown in my answer.

Comment: [Copy array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085) and [Fastest way to duplicate an array in JavaScript - slice vs. 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers and the links both of you, specially @hev1 for the modifications to my code . Didn't know it pointed to the same array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are modifying the array while iterating over it, which changes its length. Although it seems you are only modifying `population`, `parents` and `populations` both refer to the same array. You can instead store the length beforehand.

```
for(let i = 0, len = parents.length; i < len - 1; i++){
```

```js
let population = [
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
]


kidsFactory()

function kidsFactory() {
    let newKid = []
    let parents = population
    for(let i = 0, len = parents.length; i < len - 1; i++){
        parent1 = parents[i]
        parent2 = parents[i+1]
        console.log('parent1 '+parent1);
        console.log('parent2 '+parent2);
        newKid.push(parent1[0], parent1[1], parent2[2], parent2[3], parent1[4], parent1[5], parent2[6], parent2[7], parent1[8], parent1[9])
        console.log(newKid);
        population.push(newKid)
        newKid=[]
        console.log(population);
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height: 100%;top: 0;}
```

You can also use spread syntax to create a shallow copy of the array.

```
let parents = [...population];
```

Comment: @DavidRomero No problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing to the same array while iterating. parents and population point to the same instance of an array. You can try creating new array while iterating.

```
let parents = [...population]
```

```js
let population = [
  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
]


kidsFactory()

function kidsFactory() {
  let newKid = []
  let parents = [...population];
  for (i = 0; i < (parents.length - 1); i++) {
    parent1 = parents[i]
    parent2 = parents[i + 1]
    console.log('parent1 ' + parent1);
    console.log('parent2 ' + parent2);
    newKid.push(parent1[0], parent1[1], parent2[2], parent2[3], parent1[4], parent1[5], parent2[6], parent2[7], parent1[8], parent1[9])
    console.log(newKid);
    population.push(newKid)
    newKid = []
    console.log(population);
  }
}
```