# useState doesn't updated - nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm using nextjs.
I have a variable: `delivery_times`.

I created this with `useState` and it's empty at first time.
then with `useEffect` function I called my api and I updated it.So far, so good.
now I added a property called `is_selected` when use click on each object. default value is `false` when it changed to `true`, my element is added a `selected` class.

```
const [delivery_times,setDeliveryTimes] = useState([])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getDeliveryTimes()
  }, []);

  const getDeliveryTimes = () =>{
    api.get('cart/delivery-times').then((res: any) => {
      setDeliveryTimes(res.delivery_times)
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }

  const setSelectedDeliveryTime = (item) => {
    
    for(var i = 0 ; i < delivery_times.length ; ++i){
      delivery_times[i].is_selected = false;
    }
    
    const objIndex = delivery_times.findIndex((obj => obj.date == item.date));
    console.log(objIndex,item)
    delivery_times[objIndex].is_selected = true;

    setDeliveryTimes(delivery_times) //it doesn't work
  }


<div className="delivery-times mt-5">
  {delivery_times.map(item => {
    return (<div onClick={()=>setSelectedDeliveryTime(item)} className={item.is_selected === true?"item selected":"item"}>
      
      <p className="date">{item.time_range}</p>
    </div>
    )
  })}
</div>
```

but `selected` class doesn't added at all.

Comment: Quick fix : `setDeliveryTimes([...delivery_times])`. Reason : mutating the state doesn't create new reference(which will be compared with older reference), hence react thinks the state hasn't changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use state needs to change in order to trigger re-render, `setDeliveryTimes(delivery_times)` sets the same array, although, one of its elements value is changed. you can do this:

```
setDeliveryTimes([...delivery_times])
```

which should trigger the re-render

Answer (score 1):

The reason being, as stated in [their doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update),
React uses [Object.is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#description) to compare the previous value of your old and new state. Therefore, when you mutated `delivery_times` and assign it back to state, react thought they were identical and therefore it doesn't bother to re-compute your state's value.

E.g.

```
const arr = [];
Object.is(arr, arr); // True
Object.is(arr, [...arr]); // False
```

As the previous answer, in order for your state to update, you'll need to update the state with a new array - There are multiple ways to [clone an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20547803/1627271), and spread is one of the most favorite, fastest and laziest way out there.

```
const setSelectedDeliveryTime = (item) => {
  // Create new array, copied from delivery_times;
  const new_delivery_times = [...delivery_times];

  for(var i = 0 ; i < new_delivery_times.length ; ++i){
    new_delivery_times[i].is_selected = false;
  }

  const objIndex = new_delivery_times.findIndex((obj => obj.date == item.date));
  new_delivery_times[objIndex].is_selected = true;

  setDeliveryTimes(new_delivery_times); // <-- notice it assigns new array.
}
```