# Replace elements in an array by index corresponding to the numbers from another array

Tags: javascript

I need to find and replace each element in the array with an index that corresponds to the numbers from another array

```
arrayA = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
arrayB = [2, 5, 6]
valueToReplace = 'X'
expectedResult = ['a', 'X', 'c', 'd', 'X', 'X', 'g']
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are `a,b,c,d,e,f,g` supposed to be string?

Comment: Yes, it's a string

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working? Read up on the basics of [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and then come back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var var arrayA = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'],
arrayB = [2,5,6],
valueToReplace = 'X';
for(let i of arrayB) {
     arrayA[i] = valueToReplace
}
console.log(arrayA);
```

Answer (score 2):

One answer has been accepted but I want to add: If you don't want to overwrite `arrayA` you can use this code, cloning array (check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3978492/13464279) also) and iterating over `arrayB` as suggested by @pilchard:

```js
let arrayA = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
const arrayB = [2,5,6]
const valueToReplace = 'X';

let expectedResult = [...arrayA];
arrayB.forEach(value => expectedResult[value-1] = valueToReplace)
console.log(expectedResult)
```

Also, to get the same output as you expect I've used `value-1` because index starts at 0, so value 2 is third position and has to be second position.

So giving positions `[2,5,6]` and expecting result `[a,X,c,d,X,X,g]` is neccessary to use `value - 1`.

```
array:    [a,X,c,d,X,X,g]
index:     0,1,2,3,4,5,6
value:         2     5,6
value-1:     1     4,5
```

Note how using `value` it will update positions 3, 6 and 7 instead of 2, 5 and 6.

Comment: It would be more efficient to first clone `arrayA` and then iterate `arrayB` as the accepted answer does, no need for a nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

you can use array.map to change the array values in each iteration:

```js
let arrayA = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ,'f', 'g']
let arrayB = [2, 5, 6]
let valueToReplace = 'X';
let result = arrayA.map((el, i)=> arrayB.includes(i + 1) ? valueToReplace : el );
console.log(result);
```