# How to read proxies from file 1 by 1 and then repeat them in same natural order in JS?

Tags: javascript, worker

I have this worker.js script where proxies are read from index.js and using Math.floor to randomize the order of the proxies and then use puppeteer to visit a URL.
in index.js:

```
const proxies = fs.readFileSync('./proxies.txt')
```

and in worker.js file:

```
const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * workerData.proxies.length);
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                    args: ['--proxy-server=' + workerData.proxies[index]],
                    headless: "new",
                    executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome'
```

I don't wish to randomize, I just wish it to execute proxy 1 by 1 and then after last one, repeat from first one in sequence.

Comment: So what's the issue? `for (let proxy of workerData.proxies) { /* do your thing */ }` [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3010840/215552)

Comment: as you might tell , i am a complete newbie at coding :P the ".length" function , should i still use it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Not unless you want to...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [making a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3978492/13762264) of `workerData.proxies` and then removing items 1 by 1 from that list [using .slice()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5767325/13762264) might do the job.

```js
var proxiesCopy = workerData.proxies.slice();

while (proxiesCopy.length > 0) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * proxiesCopy.length);
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--proxy-server=' + workerData.proxies[index]],
        headless: "new",
        executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome'
    })
    // Possibly more puppeteer stuff etc...

    proxiesCopy.splice(index, 1)
}
```