# javascript concat running time

Tags: javascript, concatenation

If I have two arrays both with 10000 items, now I want to merge them into one array, so I do it with concat:

```
 array1=array1.concat(array2);
```

but does any body know what is the running time? constant or N? is there a better way to merger them in term of speed. thanks for any tips.

Comment: This is a little confusing: "concatenation" and "merging" are two different things to do with lists.

Comment: well..I want to merge two arrays into one, but we use concat in javascript, am I right?

Comment: @bingjie2680: I suppose the difference is that "concatenation" means simply appending array2 to array1 whereas "merging" could mean that the items of the two arrays are interspersed by some logic (e.g. sorted order).  You probably just mean concatenation here.

Comment: @maerics, Yes, exactly, order is not important.

Comment: This [site](http://jsperf.com/) is for testing the performance of your scripts, if you decide to test this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I doubt that the ECMAScript specification mandates any big-oh performance requirements for any operations, so it will be implementation dependent.  The only way to verify would be to write a benchmark and run it on your target interpreters.

That said, I would guess that most JavaScript interpreters implement Arrays as vector-type arrays rather than linked lists, so the concat operation is likely to be `O(n)` on most engines.

Comment: if I would like two arrays to be linked list, do you have ideas how I could implement it in this case.

Comment: @bingjie2680 you'd have to implement your own linked list representation. There's no way to tell the JavaScript runtime how to make its arrays work, in other words.