# What is Time Complexity for string concatenation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, time-complexity, string-concatenation

I am learning algorithms. And I didn't find any articles about how to calculate Time Complexity of string concatenation in JavaScript.

```
function concatString(str1, str2) {
  // return str1 + str2;
  // return str1.concat(str2)
}
```

We can concat strings using operator '+' or using built-in method String.prototype.concat

Which method is better? What is the Time Complexity of both methods?

Comment: How many characters would the function have to touch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript concat running time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434726/javascript-concat-running-time)

Comment: if you wrap such a fundamental thing in a user function, what calls it is going to be awful

Comment: If you don't have an *actual* performance issue that you've determined involves string concatenation efficiency, then worrying about it is a waste of time.

Comment: Count of characters is dynamic. 
Your question is about Array.prototype.concat()

Comment: I am learning algorithms. And I didn't find any articles about how to calculate Time Complexity of string concatenation in JavaScript. That is why my function is such simple.

Comment: The problem is that in a language like JavaScript, all you know is what string concatenation is supposed to *do*.  Each runtime can implement it any way it wants to.

Comment: @Pointy I'm going to disagree with you there - we should be encouraging mental curiosity, not _punishing_ people for asking _questions-we-feel-people-shouldnt-ask_.

Comment: @Dai pretty sure they’re speaking from a practical standpoint. It’s very unlikely OP will ever need to actually know the answer to this, and it’s much more likely they’re prematurely optimizing. However, if OP is asking from a theoretical standpoint and perhaps from curiosity from their uni modules then it makes a lot of sense to ask this question and it shouldn’t be seen as negative.

Comment: Well honestly I hardly think I've "punished" anybody. It's advice, and advice that I strongly believe to be valuable. Pondering the workings of JavaScript string concatenation is not "learning algorithms"; we don't even know what the algorithm is.

Comment: The time complexities are identical, because there’s no reason why one method should have a less efficient algorithm than the other. `+` is likely faster because it doesn’t need to read properties such as the string’s [[Prototype]], or `concat`, it doesn’t need to coerce the string to an object, and doesn’t need an additional stack frame for the method call. However, most of these things are likely optimized away. Since [string concatenation](//tc39.es/ecma262/#string-concatenation) isn’t specified in detail, it’s implementation dependent, but `+` is almost certainly the fastest way.

Comment: To be constructive: if string concatenation is something you're curious about from an algorithmic standpoint, you'd be much better off thinking about it in the context of a language like C.  Then you can contemplate alternative string representations that provide efficiency trade-offs compared to the C way of storing strings. Why? Because in a language like that, you're working with the low-level data structure directly. You can see what has to happen step-by-step.

Comment: See: [Rope (data structure)](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28data_structure%29). I believe strings are ropes in JS.

Comment: @SebastianSimon (Disclaimer: I used to work on the Chakra JS engine): The ECMAScript spec does not mandate any particular internal representation of strings and (last time I checked) the spec did not specify any upper-bounds on time or space complexity of operations on string values either.

Comment: A practical answer is that strings are typically implemented as characters stored in sequential locations.  Concatenation is typically done by allocating a buffer large enough to store both strings and copying them in.  O(n) where n is the sum of the operand strings' lengths.

Comment: @Dai I know string representation isn’t specified; I meant to say strings are _implemented_ as ropes in JS. However, I may be misremembering this.

Comment: @SebastianSimon In this context, _representation_ and _implementation_ are the same thing (by "representation" I meant "internal representation"), and nothing authoritative says that JS strings are ropes.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation, the difference between using `+` and `concat()` is that `contat()` will convert the argument directly to a string while the `+` operator will convert the operands to a primitive value and then into a string. Summarizing, it will not make a significant difference.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat#description

---

The time complexity of concat operations in another language like Java is usually O(n^2), and is a common practice to use a StringBuilder to make it O(n). In JavaScript though, there is an optimized implementation of concatenation based on the rope data structure, making the time complexity O(log n) in most cases.

https://josephmate.github.io/java/javascript/stringbuilder/2020/07/27/javascript-does-not-need-stringbuilder.html