# How to modify values of a given array within a method without modifying the actual array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote this test,

```
public class test {     
    public static String[] foo(String[] myArray, int index) {
        myArray[index] = "world";
        return myArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] fooArray = new String[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
            fooArray[i] = "hello";
        }

        foo(fooArray, 9);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
            System.out.println(fooArray[i]);
        }
    } 
}
```

which results in this output

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
world
```

So `foo` basically just changes a value in the array and returns this modified array. But the actual `fooArray` is being modified by the `foo` method (as evidenced by the output). Is there an efficient way to pass the array `fooArray` and have it not modified by `foo`?

I know that I could make a copy of the `fooArray` in the method like

```
    public String[] void foo(String[] myArray, int index) {
        String[] copy = new String[];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
            copy[i] = myArray[i];
        }

        copy[index] = "world";
        return copy; 
    }
```

but I am planning to do this modification on arrays of a size in the thousands and also I am planning to this millions (or even billions) of times during runtime so I don't think that copying the entire array every time would be an efficient solution (I need to get a reasonable runtime).

Comment: check this one first ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491405/javascript-passing-arrays-to-functions-by-value-leaving-original-array-unaltere

Comment: So you make a modification but don't assign it to anything. What is the point of the `foo()` method anyway? Are you aware that Java is pass-by-value?

Comment: Welcome to the magic world of references! You have to effectively copy the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best solution is [Arrays.copyOf(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[],%20int))

It uses System.arraycopy(...) 
for example in Arrays.java you can find:

```
public static byte[] copyOf(byte[] original, int newLength) {
    byte[] copy = new byte[newLength];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

And [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) says it is efficient because it is native method and just copies the old block of memory to new one.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do `fooArray.clone()`
For example:

```
foo(fooArray.clone(), 9);
```

This will clone the array and when you call `foo` it will not modify `fooArray`.

Comment: Using `clone` is a bad habit. Better use `System. arraycopy()`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int) or `Arrays.copyOf(...)` as Vitaly has mentioned.

Comment: read this: http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/10/cloneable-interface-is-broken-in-java/