# Unexpected binding in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, datatable

I'm having a very weird problem in my Angular 2 application using the PrimeNG DataTable. It's possible to change data in my DataTable, using the `[editable]"true"` syntax.

The data in the DataTable is called = `inschrijvingen`. 
I'm doing `this.originalInschrijvingen = this.inschrijvingen` to create a 'copy' before the user can change the data so I can compare the changes in a later stage. But for some reason is the DataTable data binding to both `originalInschrijvingen` and `inschrijvingen`.

Here is my code:

```
onRowSelectUser(event) { //This is a different DataTable than the editable DataTable
    this.getGebruikerZijnInschrijvingen(res => {
      this.createRoleID(res => {
        let selectedIds = this.gebruikerZijnInschrijvingen.map(it => it.DefUnitID);
        this.selectedInschrijvingen = this.inschrijvingen.filter(inv => selectedIds.indexOf(inv.ID) != -1);
        this.originalInschrijvingen = this.selectedInschrijvingen;
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: maybe reading about references in programming would help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)

Comment: Thanks for this! I didn't knew it was referencing instead of 'copying'. Thanks!

Comment: @Pengyy Thanks for the reply but I think I found an answer already = [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21896214/4461137)

Comment: @Milan_w ok, for me, I would recommend you avoid using the way mentioned by that link for `json.parse` and `json.stringify` may lead to problems.

Comment: @Pengyy Okay, I'll look into your solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`this.selectedInschrijvingen` seems to be an array and in Javascript when you assign one array to another using `=` operator they are copied by reference, hence they represent same array.

You can do below,

```
this.originalInschrijvingen = this.selectedInschrijvingen.slice();
```

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array
>   into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included).
>   The original array will not be modified.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!! At least I understand now why this was happening, it was driving me crazy! But your solution doesn't quite work, it still updates both arrays? Any more ideas?

Comment: I have found a way to do this. [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21896214/4461137) had an idea without any upvotes, but it seems to be working for me.