# JS is changing 2d-array values, might it be another function interfering?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Short summary: I have written some code that fills up a 2-dimensional array. When I display this array, everything is perfect. Now I give this 2d-array as a parameter to a function. When I call the function inside of

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = myFunction(int, array);
```

it shows exactly the right values. However, I don't want to display them, I want to further use them. As the function returns an array (one dimensional), I tried

```
var my_result_array = myFunction(int, array);
```

I have also tried push() and pre-defined arrays or accessing just single elements.

The thing is, as soon as I have the function called in my document, the array I am giving to the function as a parameter is changing! I took care that there are no similiar names, but I just can`t figure out, why it is always changing my parameter array, therefore destroying the calculation but working fine if I use it in the document.getElementbyId part.

Any suggestions?

Edit for more code:
I try to keep it short and explainatory. I am creating an empty array with a dimension given by `mat_dimension_js`

```
var berechnungs_array = new Array(mat_dimension_js);
    for (var i = 0; i < mat_dimension_js; i++){ 
        berechnungs_array[i] = new Array(mat_dimension_js);
    }
```

I then fill this array up with values. If I print the array, everything is fine, the values are where they belong. I then feed this array to `myFunction()`

Sorry for the mess, I have also tried it without creating an array A again.
I then try to grab the output of myFunction() as told above, but as soon as I do that, somehow the array I have given as a parameter changes.

Comment: Could be a scope issue. Do you mind sending some more code? Plus make sure you don't have a global variable with the same name.

Comment: Edited with more code, I will double-check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in JavaScript are passed **by reference**, meaning that any changes you do to the array passed inside the function will also be saved in the actual array.

In addition, `A = mat_array;` **does not create a copy of `mat_array`, but another pointer to it** (meaning that both variables refer to the exact same array object internally).

To properly make a copy of a 1D array, calling `.slice(0)` should do the trick. However, for 2D arrays, you need to do this recursively.

See [Javascript passing arrays to functions by value, leaving original array unaltered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14491446/7692859)

[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you! I cloned the array inside the function I am calling instead of referencing it by
```
var A = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array_param.length; i++)
    A[i] = array_param[i].slice();
```
Worked like a charm! Thanks!