# How to move 3 elements of array one by one in each of loop iterations?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, recursion

I have an array `[1,1,1,0]` (any size of), the minimum length of array and number 1 is 3. I want to keep moving the value of 1s 1 element up so it could move to `[0,1,1,1]`, then back to `[1,1,1,0]`.

My loop sort of work in recursive mode, but I'm not sure how to reset the values, so after 4 loops, my entire array is filled with 0's.

More lengthily array would traverse as so:

Example:

```
[1,1,1,0,0,0]-> [0,1,1,1,0,0]-> [0,0,1,1,1,0]-> [0,0,0,1,1,1]-> 
[1,1,0,0,0,1]-> [1,1,1,0,0,0]-> [0,1,1,1,0,0]-> [0,0,1,1,1,0]->
```

And so on for ever...

Code:

```
function flip(images, active) {
    var new_active = active;

    setTimeout(function() {
        active.reverse();
        active[active.length] = 0;
        active.reverse();
        active.pop();

        for(var i = 0; i < active.length; i++) {
            alert(active[i]);
        }

        flip(images, active);
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: can't quite understand what you want to do. Is [1,1,1,0]->[0,1,1,1]->[1,0,1,1]->[1,1,0,1]->[1,1,1,0] ok? give us an example.

Comment: I have added an example with larger array size.

Comment: that makes it easy to understand. maybe it's called rotating, did you saw the 3 answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on which direction you want to do, I would suggest using [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), or [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) and [`unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift).

Basically, `shift()` and `unshift()` add or remove an element from the front of the array, and `push()` and `pop()` add or remove an element from the back of the array.

For the example you have given, you'll probably want to `pop()` off the end of the array and `unshift()` to the front:

```
function rotateArray(arr) {
    var element = arr.pop();
    arr.unshift(element);
}
// Repeat in loop, timeout, etc. as necessary
```

Comment: Ah, exactly what I needed with an example. Thank you.

Comment: You could also add a `dir` parameter (direction) and implement as such: `function rotateArray(arr, dir) { dir = !dir || dir > 0;  arr[dir ? "unshift" : "push"](arr[dir ? "pop" : "shift"]()); }` - see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxanykaw/)

Answer (score 2):

- First pop(store it).So [abcd]->[abc] and you have stored d.
- Reverse. So [abc]->[cba].
- Add the popped element. So [cba]->[cbad]
- Reverse. So [cbad]->[dabc].

I hope you wanted that? 
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985260/javascript-array-rotate) too.

---

Upvote if it helped you. :(

Comment: Thanks to the existence of both `push()`/`pop()` and `unshift()`/`shift()`, you don't need to reverse the array. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28329759/129655.

Comment: Fair enough. You had the right idea from algorithmic perspective; just take this as another learning opportunity. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    startIndex = arr.indexOf(1),
    sliceLength = 3,
    slice;

while(arr[arr.length - 1] === 0) {
    // slice out the 1's (modifies the original array)
    slice = arr.splice(startIndex, sliceLength);
    // splice the 1's back in, one spot over
    arr.splice.apply(arr, [++startIndex, 0].concat(slice));
    console.log(arr);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sn7ujb90/1/