# Reorder an array around an index

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

My issue is very simple to explain, but figuring out the most efficient way of doing it is proving difficult.

I am trying to reorder an array starting at a particular index in the array.

What I have:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

What I want:

```
array = [3,4,5,1,2];
```

What I've done:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var arr1 = array.slice(array.indexOf(3), array.length);
var arr2 = array.slice(0, array.indexOf(3));

arr1.push(arr2);

var newArray = arr1.join(); // [3,4,5,1,2];
```

As you can see, there is quite a bit going on for what is seemingly a simple task.  If you have any suggestions on how to improve this I'd be grateful.  Either vanilla JS or Underscore/Lodash is fine.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985260/javascript-array-rotate

Comment: `var newArray = array.slice(array.indexOf(3), array.length).concat(array.slice(0, array.indexOf(3))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about one line:

```
var array = array.slice(2, array.length).concat(array.slice(0, 2));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vqnmL07j/)

Answer (score 1):

This will not get you a flat array at the end :

```
arr1.push(arr2);
var newArray = arr1.join();
```

what you need to do is to call the method `Array.prototype.concat`

```
var newArray = arr1.concat(arr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

More functional-like approach:

```
var reorder = function(array, index) {
  return _.flatten(_.partition(array, function(v, i) {return i < index}).reverse())
};
reorder([1,2,3,4,5], 3);
```

Or instead of `_.flatten`, you can use `_.union.apply(null, ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

A nice easy way with underscore is to use the [**first**](http://underscorejs.org/#first) and [**rest**](http://underscorejs.org/#rest) functions and concatenate the results. Here's a mixin that does just that:

```
    _.mixin( { reorder: function(list, index){
        return _.rest(list,index).concat(_.first(list,index));
    }});

    var result = _.reorder(array, 3)
```