# What is the best way to shift first three elements of array to the end?

Tags: arrays

I have the array ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
I need a function to shift abc to the end of the array - ["d", "e", "a", "b", "c"]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Array rotate()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985260/javascript-array-rotate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function rotate(a, n) {
  // The modulo here is a performance optimization... rotating by the length of the array has no effect. E.g. in this example, rotating 8 is the same as rotating 3.
  for (var i = 0; i < n % a.length; i++) {
    a.push(a.shift());
  }
}

var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

rotate(a, 3);

console.log(a);

// Output:
// [ 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

**EDIT**

Non-destructive version using `slice`:

```
function rotate(a, n) {
  n %= a.length;
  return a.slice(n).concat(a.slice(0, n));
}

var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

console.log(rotate(a, 3));

// Output:
// [ 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

**EDIT2**

In response to the follow-up question in a comment, here's how you would copy the elements instead of moving them. (This is the non-destructive version.)

```
function copy(a, n) {
  n %= a.length;
  return a.concat(a.slice(0, n));
}

var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

console.log(copy(a, 3));

// Output:
// [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

Or here's an in-place version of `copy`:

```
function copy(a, n) {
  for (var i = 0; i < n % a.length; i++) {
    a.push(a[i]);
  }
}

var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

copy(a, 3);

console.log(a);

// Output:
// [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

Comment: Great!
How to change this function in order to copy elements?
To get output: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c' ]

Comment: Yes perfect. But if I use this function more than once - how can I copy to array next symbols?
If I add "abc", at the next time I want to add "def" (depending on n parameter of your function)

Comment: @MikeDiam I'm not sure what you mean. Could you give an example of the input and output you're expecting? E.g. input: `['a', 'b', 'c'], 3`, output: ???

Comment: I have done it by adding 3rd parameter to the function as s (times of function runs)
a.push(a[i+n*(s-1)]);