# How to check if the current url is greater than the first url in an array without using .indexOf()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a previous button that will cycle through an array of urls. I got it to work as intended, however I had to use .indexOf() when checking if the current url is greater than the first item in the array. Since the urls will most likely be changing, I don't want to specify the exact url.

Here is the working example:

```
var pageList = ["january_28-2016.html", "february_06-2016.html", "march_17-2016.html"]
var url = window.location.pathname; 
var page = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1); 
var currentPosition = pageList.indexOf(page); 

document.getElementById('prev-btn').onclick = function(){
    if(currentPosition>pageList.indexOf("january_28-2016.html")) {window.location = pageList[--currentPosition];}
    else {window.location = pageList[pageList.length-1];}
}
```

I tried

```
 if(currentPosition>pageList[0])
```

and

```
var page1 = pageList[0]
if(currentPosition>page1)
```

but could not get it to function. Is there a better way of accomplishing this without using pageList.indexOf("january_28-2016.html")) to get the first element?

Comment: In javascript you can find elements in arrays by its description too.. Like: pagelist["january_28-2016.html"]

Comment: Are you sure the `pageList` array holds the full URL? It seems it's only the last part. Also the `Array.prototype.rotate()` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/38010679/4543207) might turn out to be useful for your application.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll take a look at the Array.prototype.rotate() solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify the index > 0.

```
if(currentPosition>0)
```

Comment: Yup, well that totally worked. I feel like an idiot. For some reason, I thought I had to specify the name of the array based on my research. array[0] for the first item and array.length-1 for the last.  I'm pretty new to all of this. Thank you for your help!