# How to build an array of dates from now with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs

Using moment.js, i need to build an array of the coming 12 months.- starting from the current month. e.g (assuming current month = December):

```
var monthsArray = [
  "December",
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  [...]
  "November"
  ]
```

My current solution only displays all 12 months of a year, without considering a "starting" month

```
  var count = 0;
  var months = [];
  while (count < 12) months.push(moment().month(count++).format("MMMM"));
```

I guess the user month with

```
_private.userMonth = moment().format('MMMM');
```

How can i apply this to build my array of months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this, among all kinds of other ways to do it.

```
var months = moment.months();
var coming12Months = months.concat(months.slice(0, moment().month())).slice(-12);

// ["December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November"]
```

This is not a particularly elegant solution, but it's effective. A thread on how to *properly* rotate an array in JS [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985260/javascript-array-rotate).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use moment's `add` function:

```
var offset = 0;
var months = [];
while (offset < 12) {
  months.push(moment().add(offset++, 'month').format('MMMM'));
}
```