# How to implement carousel with an array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array of items representing a virtual carousel.

```
const carousel = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
let currentIndex = 0;

function move (amount) {
   const l = items.length;  // in case carousel size changes

   // need to update currentIndex

   return carousel[currentIndex];

}
```

What is a clean or clever way to handle moving left when `currentIndex == 0` and moving right when `currentIndex == length-1`?

I have thought about this before and have never come with anything very clever or concise.

Comment: _"what is the cleanest and cleverest way to handle the change when moving 'left' when `currentIndex` is 0 and moving 'right' when `currentIndex` is length - 1?"_ What do you mean by "cleanest and cleverest"? Where is `change` used? What is expected result?

Comment: Add the amount and mod the value by the list length. Adding 4 from 5 in a list of 8 items should return 1 — since 9 % 8 = 1.

Comment: might want to look into using a library? that would be the 'cleverest' way. as for 'clean' that would change as your requirements change - async calls to update contents? items can be images with captions, webpage snippets, text with background? Your question is too broad to answer succinctly

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 OP is asking, in essence, about how to deal with a [circular array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer); hardly unanswerable.

Comment: @royhowie I hope you realize that your answer makes certain assumptions as to what the OP requires as well. As for 'clean' and 'cleverest', an 'if' statement suffices to handle circular array.

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331if/else will not work well when change is more extreme than 1 or -1. @royhowie's answer is generic and the best way to do this.

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 try implementing it yourself - where an array holds 5 items and you change the carousel position by more than 1 places, for example 3 places, or 12 places

Comment: an 'if' can contain all the logic roy has included in his solution. anyway it seems that OP has received the answer he was looking for, there's no need for me to be pedantic here.

Comment: Show me the money! Add an answer with an if/else solution thats as generic as the accepted answer and I will at the very least upvote it, theres not one right answer here

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### short answer

Implement a [circular array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) via [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). Given a distance to move, to calculate the appropriate index:

```
// put distance in the range {-len+1, -len+2, ..., -1, 0, 1, ..., len-2, len-1}
distance = distance % len
// add an extra len to ensure `distance+len` is non-negative
new_index = (index + distance + len) % len
```

### long answer

Use [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) much like how you'd read a typical analog clock. The premise is to add two integers, divide by a integer, and keep the remainder. For example, `13 = 3 (mod 10)` because `13` is `1*10 + 3` and `3` is `0*10 + 3`.

But why did we choose to arrange `3` and `13` as we did? To answer that, we consider the [Euclidean division algorithm (EDA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division). It says for two integers `a` and `b` there exists unique integers `q` and `r` such that

```
a = b*q + r
```

with `0 ≤ r < b`. This is more powerful than you'd think: it allows us to "work modulo n."

That is, we can say `a = b (mod n)` *iff* there are unique integers `q1`, `r1`, `q2`, and `r2` such that

```
a = n * q1 + r1,   0 ≤ r1 < n
b = n * q2 + r2,   0 ≤ r2 < n
```

and `r1` equals `r2`. We call `r1` and `r2` the "remainders."

To go back to the previous example, we now know why `13 = 3 (mod 10)`. The EDA says `13 = 1*10 + 3` and that `1` and `3` are the only `q` and `r` satisfying the necessary constraints; by similar logic, `3 = 0*10 + 3`. Since the remainders are equal, we say that `13` and `3` are equal when "working mod 10."

Fortunately, JavaScript implements a [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) natively. Unfortunately, we need to watch out for a quirk, i.e., the modulo operator keeps the sign of its operands. This gives you some results like `-6 % 5 == -1` and `-20 % 7 == -6`. While perfectly valid mathematical statements (check why), this doesn't help us when it comes to array indices.

**Lemma 1:** `a + n = a (mod n)`
**Lemma 2:** `-1 = n-1 (mod n)`
**Lemma 3:** `-a = n-a (mod n)`

The way to overcome this is to "trick" JavaScript into using the correct sign. Suppose we have an array with length `len` and current index `index`; we want to move the index by a distance `d`:

```
// put `d` within the range {-len+1, -len+2, ..., -2, -1, -0}
d = d % len
// add an extra len to ensure `d+len` is non-negative
new_index = (index + d + len) % len
```

We accomplish this by first putting `d` within the range `{-len+1, -len+2, ..., -2, -1, -0}`. Next, we add an extra `len` to make sure the distance we're moving is within the range `{1, 2, ..., len-1, len}`, thereby ensuring the result of the `%` operation has a positive sign. We know this works because `(-a+b) + a = b (mod a)`. Then we just set the new index to `index + d + len (mod len)`.

More detailed implementation:

```
class Carousel {
  // assumes `arr` is non-empty
  constructor (arr, index = 0) {
    this.arr = arr
    this.index = index % arr.length
  }
  // `distance` is an integer (...-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ...)
  move (distance) {
    let len = this.arr.length
    distance = distance % len
    let new_index = (this.index + distance + len) % len
    this.index = new_index
    return this.arr[this.index]
  }
}

// usage:
let c = new Carousel(['a','b','c','d','e'], 1) // position pointer set at 'b'
c.move(-1)  // returns 'a' as (1 + -1 + 5) % 5 == 5 % 5 == 0
c.move(-1)  // returns 'e' as (0 + -1 + 5) % 5 == 4 % 5 == 4
c.move(21)  // returns 'a' as (4 + 21 + 5) % 5 == 30 % 5 == 0
```

Comment: Why mod out the distance? A simple `this.index = (whateverDistance + this.index) % this.arr.length` is all you need.

Comment: @Sukima explained inside `Carousel.move` more thoroughly, but JS keeps the sign of %, so `(0 + -13) % 5 == -3`, but `-3` is not a valid array index; adding `len` makes sure the result is within the range `{0, 1, 2, ..., len-2, len-1}`.

Comment: your answer is good because it's generic, I changed the question to be more generic as well

Comment: hmmm you may need to make sure distance is less than array length? seems like that needs to happen, otherwise should work

Comment: @AlexanderMills that's why I added the line `distance = distance % len`

Comment: @royhowie Huh, hmmm, i think i need to go do some more research. I know i've seen it before. Good call.

Comment: Ok i see my mistake. @royhowie thank you for the extra clarification. I see it now.

Comment: @Sukima I've added an explanation of modular arithmetic and the Euclidean Division Algorithm.

Comment: @Sukima perhaps you're thinking of a [circular buffer/array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)?

Comment: Yes, though I am still trying to learn best implementation designs for a circular buffer in vanilla JS.

Comment: Your original answer said use "modular addition" at the very top which I think is most useful

Comment: @AlexanderMills noted; I added a reference to that back (modular arithmetic is a better name than modular addition).

Answer (score 3):

I had implemented an [`Array.prototype.rotate()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38010679/4543207) a while back. It might come very handy for this job. Here is the code;

```js
Array.prototype.rotate = function(n) {
var len = this.length;
return !(n % len) ? this.slice()
                  : this.map((e,i,a) => a[(i + (len + n % len)) % len]);
};
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    b = a.rotate(10);
console.log(JSON.stringify(b));
    b = a.rotate(-10);
console.log(JSON.stringify(b));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
currentIndex = currentIndex + change;
if (currentIndex >= l)  currentIndex = 0;
if (currentIndex < 0) currentIndex = l -  1;
```

This will modify the index, check if it's broken possible values and adjust to either 'side' of the carousel.

Comment: practical but a bit boring :)

Comment: Learn to love the mod (`%`) operator. It excels at array index wrapping.

Comment: Saw the mod used above, love it! Will hopefully have a chance to play with it in the future. Alex is on the money, boring, but it works. :^)

Comment: well, it won't work when you "spin" the carousel by more than 1 place :)