# Opposite of shift() in JS or other solutions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to take an array and have it loop around itself. I already found a simple solution for having it loop around itself backwards:

```
array = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Animal', 'Pig']
array[array.length] = array[0];
array.shift();
```

This as expected turns out as ['Cat', 'Animal', 'Pig', 'Dog']. How would I make it do the opposite in a similar manner. By doing the opposite I mean turning out ['Pig', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Animal']. I have tried to find the opposite of .shift() for this but can't find anything. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Opposite of shift is [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)?

Comment: `Array#reverse()` reverses the array which seems what you are asking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [`Array#pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

> The **`pop()`** method removes the last element from an array and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array.

and [`Array#unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift).

> The **`unshift()`** method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array and returns the new length of the array.

```js
var array = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Animal', 'Pig'];

array.push(array.shift());
console.log(array); // ["Cat", "Animal", "Pig", "Dog"]

array = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Animal', 'Pig'];

array.unshift(array.pop());
console.log(array); // ["Pig", "Dog", "Cat", "Animal"]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking for a  [`rotate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1985471/3270037) function:

```js
Array.prototype.rotate = (function() {
    // save references to array functions to make lookup faster
    var push = Array.prototype.push,
        splice = Array.prototype.splice;

    return function(count) {
        var len = this.length >>> 0, // convert to uint
            count = count >> 0; // convert to int

        // convert count to value in range [0, len)
        count = ((count % len) + len) % len;

        // use splice.call() instead of this.splice() to make function generic
        push.apply(this, splice.call(this, 0, count));
        return this;
    };
})();

a = [1,2,3,4,5];
a.rotate(1);
console.log(a.join(',')); //2,3,4,5,1
a.rotate(-1);
console.log(a.join(',')); //1,2,3,4,5
a.rotate(-1);
console.log(a.join(',')); //5,1,2,3,4
```