# Array Left Rotation in Javascript will log to console but not return

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on the array left rotation on Hackerrank.  The solution that I have will console.log the array containing the correct result, but will not work using return.  Here's the detail from their site - "Print a single line of n space-separated integers denoting the final state of the array after performing d left rotations."  I've read that the issue might be with asynchronous functions running in node.js, but I'm not sure how to work around that.

```js
// sample input - 1 2 3 4 5
// sample output - 5 1 2 3 4

function rotLeft(a, d) {
  var arr = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= a; i++){
      arr.push(i)
    };
    for (var j = 1; j <= d; j++){
     arr.shift(arr.push(j))
    }
    console.log(arr.toString()); // <-- this will print the desired output.
    return arr.toString(); // <-- no return from this.
}


rotLeft(5, 4)
```

Comment: Of course it does, try `console.log(rotLeft(5, 4));`

Comment: There is nothing asynchronous here

Comment: @LGSon Hackerrank throws a runtime error with that solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have also been trying to solve this problem. There are some issues in your current solution. See you have to create an array and store the array passed from parameters in it. 
What you have done is just creating a new array and adding the sequence of numbers of elements that should be in it e.g `a.length=5` you are doing `arr.push 1 2 3 4 5`. But the question wants an array of user's choice. Second thing is that you should return an array not the string.

So this is the solution of this problem:

```
function rotLeft(a, d) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        arr.push(a[i]);
    };
    for (var j = 1; j <= d; j++) {
        arr.shift(arr.push(arr[0]));
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: I had a similar answer to Justin's: https://codepen.io/HappyHands31/pen/YMdpzN?editors=1112

I don't get why my code is logging the correct answer in my text editor console, but HackerRank does not accept it. In fact, HackerRank is saying that my code isn't producing an output? 

Your code works in HackerRank but then it just returns an empty array in my console.

Comment: I think this is better : 

const splited = a.slice(0,d)
const restOfSplit = a.slice(d, a.length)
return (restOfSplit.concat(splited))

Comment: I think first for loop is unnecessary because you are just copying ''a'' inside ''arr'' we can  do this for copying array:
var arr = [...a];

Answer (score 6):

I'll give my solution to this problem for future visitors.

you can do this in **one line** as follows :

```
function rotLeft(a, d)
 {
    let rslt = a.slice(d).concat(a.slice(0,d));
    return rslt
 }
```

You need to *split* the initial array at the *d'th* position in two parts, and simply swap those two.

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array
>   into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included).
>   The original array will not be modified.

```
var animals = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant'];

console.log(animals.slice(2));
// expected output: Array ["camel", "duck", "elephant"]

console.log(animals.slice(2, 4));
// expected output: Array ["camel", "duck"]

console.log(animals.slice(1, 5));
// expected output: Array ["bison", "camel", "duck", "elephant"]
```

Comment: Wish it was a bit *clearer* to read in terms of syntax (nothing wrong with it, just IMO). Would this be O(1)? I mean it just splits and concatenates... if not constant time I would say it's linear at most. Thanks for sharing! I'm trying to learn more about data structures and you made me rethink how I approach problems. My approach was O(n^2) I think... I was iterating over the whole array!

Comment: You are correct, here I prioritized efficiency rather than readability, you can always split the code into multiple variables and make it clearer.
String slicing is so fast in JavaScript and optimized to O(1).

Comment: great solution but if d is greater than a.length then it won't work. Here is my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/63606959/569751

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
function rotLeft(a, d){
let arr=a

for(let j=0;j<=d-1;j++){
    arr.push(arr[0])
    arr.shift()
}

return arr
}
```

Comment: This question already has many answers, your answer doesn't add any new information or a new solution to the original question.

Comment: can you please re-format your code?

Comment: can you please reformat the code

Answer (score 4):

```html
function rotLeft(a, d) {
    return [...a.slice(d - a.length), ...a.slice(0, d - a.length)]
}
```

Comment: This version will be faster)) -> 
a.slice(d - a.length).concat(a.slice(0, d - a.length))

Answer (score 3):

You really don't need two loops. To rotate left *n* places:

```
function RotateLeft(arr, n) {
  return arr.map(() => {
    if (n === arr.length) {
      n = 0;
    }
        
    return arr[n++];
  });
}

var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
var places = 4;

console.log(RotateLeft(array, places));
//[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,0,1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is that hackerrank expects the return value from `rotLeft` to be an *array*, not a string of space-separated numbers. The instructions don't make that clear, unfortunately. As you can see in the pre-defined `main` function that you aren't supposed to alter:

```
  // ...
  const a = readLine().split(' ').map(aTemp => parseInt(aTemp, 10));
  const result = rotLeft(a, d);
  ws.write(result.join(' ') + '\n'); // <--- result must be an array for .join to work
  ws.end();
}
```

Your code also has some bugs. (Arrays are zero-indexed, for one - they're not 1-indexed. Also, `i <= a` isn't the right condition - `a` is the *array*, so you'd need to use `a.length`.) Try this function instead, it's a lot simpler and seems to pass all the test cases:

```
function rotLeft(a, d) {
  return [...a.slice(d), ...a.slice(0, d - a.length)]
}
```

Comment: Ohh I see.  I thought that 'a' was the final length of the array, and you're supposed to build it up to that length.  I also started the loops at 1 so the output would be "5 1 2 3 4", otherwise it would throw a 0 in between the 5 and 1 in the final output.  Can you explain the return statement that you're suggesting?  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: It's called [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) - basically, it's a single array composed of the elements from the first `slice` followed by the elements of the second `slice`.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you so much for the information!!  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Without using any extra loop and function

```
function rotLeft(a, d) {
    var arr = [];
    var l = 0;
    for(let i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        if(i >= d){ 
            arr[i-d] = a[i]
        }else{
            arr[a.length-d+l] = a[i];
            l = i+1;
        }
    }
    return arr
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check my solution and explained in this article

https://medium.com/@aamirafridi/how-to-solve-hackerranks-left-rotation-array-challenge-javascript-c032527802a7

```js
function rotLeft(a, d) {
  d = d % a.length;
  if (d === 0) return a;
  return a.concat(a.splice(0, d));
}

console.log(rotLeft([1,2,3,4,5],1));
console.log(rotLeft([1,2,3,4,5],2));
console.log(rotLeft([1,2,3,4,5],3));
console.log(rotLeft([1,2,3,4,5],4));
console.log(rotLeft([1,2,3,4,5],5));
console.log(rotLeft([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],5));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution

```
function rotLeft(a, d) {
        
        let arr = [...a];
        
        for(let i = 1; i <= d; i++){
            arr.push(arr.shift())
        }
            
        return arr
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered it like this and it is pretty simple

```
function rotLeft(a, d) {
    for(var i = 1; i <= d; i++) {
        a.push(a.shift());
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above scenarios. Nothing is working for me. But I resolved the issue myself. Hackers in rotation program.

First check d assign the value is '4' or not 
ex:- `const d = parseInt(nd[1], 10);` instead of `const d = parseInt(nd[2], 10)`

### goto rotation method:

```js
function rotLeft(a, d) {
    let i = 0;
    while (i < d) {
        a.push(a.shift());
        i++;
    }
    console.log(a);
    return a;
}
```

It's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this algo:

For example, given the inputs as:

```js
var xArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var numberOfLeftRotations = 4;
var newArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++) {
  var newIndex = (i + numberOfLeftRotations) % xArray.length;
  newArray[i] = xArray[newIndex];
}
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using any built-in method you can write your own javascript function.

try this.

```js
function swap(arr,idx1,idx2){
    let temp = arr[idx1];
    arr[idx1] = arr[idx2];
    arr[idx2] = temp;
}

function rotation(arr,n){
    let j = 0;
    while(j<n){
        for(let i = 0; i<arr.length-1; i++){
            swap(arr,i,i+1);
        }
        j++;
    }
  console.log(arr);
   return arr;
}
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
rotation(arr,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function rotLeft(a, d) {
const result = []
const l = a.length
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    const dt = i - d < 0
        ? l + i - d
        : i + d >= l ? i - d : i + d
    console.log("i=" + i + ", dt=" + dt)
    result[dt] = a[i]

}
return result
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```js
function rotLeft (a, d) {
  if(d === 0) {
    return a
    }
  
  return a.concat(a.splice(0, d))
}

console.log(rotLeft([1,2,3,4,5], 4))
```

the simplest one. You don't have to read above all smart boy's bunch of extra unnecessary sentences.

Answer (score 1):

In a real coding interview, you won't be able to use any helper functions from Javascript (100% interviewer will ask you to solve the problem with simple for loops or recursion) so you should use only basics: for loops or recursion

One line solution which will do the job but the interviewer won't accept this solution:

```
function rotLeft(a,d){
    return [...a.slice(d, a.length),  ...a.slice(0, d)]
}
```

Solution with for loops:

```
function rotLeft(a, d) {
    let l = a.length;
    
    let temp = [];
    
    for(let i = 0; i < l; i++){
        temp[i] = a[i];
    }  
      
    for (let i = 0; i < l - d; i++ ){
        a[i] = temp[d + i]
    }
    
    for (let i = 0; i < d; i++){  
        a[i + (l - d)] = temp[i]
    }
    return a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would pass all the test cases as array value might be different than [1,2,3,5,5]

```
function rotLeft(a, d) {
  var arr = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= a; i++){
      arr.push(a[i])
    };
    for (var j = 1; j < d; j++){
        arr.shift(arr.push(a[j]))
    }
    console.log(arr); // <-- this will print the desired output.
    return arr; // <-- no return from this.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function rotLeft(a, d) {
    let array = [];
    for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        if(i>=d){
           array[i-d] = a[i] 
        } else {
           array[i-d+a.length] = a[i];
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is what I did, without loop

```js
function rotLeft(a, d) {
  const splited = a.slice(0,d)
  const restOfSplit = a.slice(d, a.length)
  return (restOfSplit.concat(splited))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one passes all the test as well:

```
function rotLeft(a, d) {
    // Write your code here
    return (a.splice(d, a.length)).concat(a.splice(0, d));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer :

```
function rotLeft(a, d) {
    for(var i=d; i<a.length; i++){
    a.unshift(a.pop());
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Hi alfan maulana! Welcome to SO! Please explain a bit your code, to let others understand it faster, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function rotLeft (a, d) {
  if(d === 0) {
    return a
    }
  
  return a.concat(a.splice(0, d))
}

console.log(rotLeft([1,2,3,4], 1))
```

This works good!