# Why is my attempt to rotate this array in javascript resulting in indexes being skipped

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, rotation

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let steps = 2
let hold = arr
let indlength = arr.length - 1
for (let i = indlength; i > indlength - steps; i--) {
  hold.unshift(arr[i])
  hold.pop()
}

console.log(hold)
```

So I am attempting to rotate this array in javascript to the right by 2 rotations. Instead of getting 4,5,1,2,3 I am getting 3,5,1,2,3. I suspect it has something to do with an index being skipped, because if I up the steps to 3, it becomes 1,3,5,1,2. Here is a repl link https://repl.it/@helixlamont/ExoticTealOpengl

Comment: This is suspicious `let hold = arr`

Comment: You know that `hold` and `arr` both refer to the same array, you didn't make a copy, right?

Comment: Same reference is the problem, try with this `let hold = [...arr];`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985260/javascript-array-rotate for good ways to rotate an array.

Comment: You're decrementing `i` but the next element to add to the beginning of the array remains in the same index location, in this case `i = arr.length - 1`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the reference you're keeping when you do this `let hold = arr;`
You should create a real copy/clone of `arr`.

An alternative is using the `spread-syntax`.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    steps = 2,
    hold = [...arr],
    indlength = arr.length - 1;

for (let i = indlength; i > indlength - steps; i--) {
  hold.unshift(arr[i]);
  hold.pop();
}

console.log(hold)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thank you @Ele , so what is the difference between the reference I created and your copy? Why is [...arr] considered a real copy?

Comment: @Helix your approach is keeping the same reference in `arr` and `hold`, so the modifications in `hold` are hitting the array `arr`.  Now, the spread-operator is doing the following `[...arr] === [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, so this a real copy/clone.

Comment: that works is very tricky and not obvious, because you use two different arrays for changing an array and keeping the other.

Comment: @NinaScholz probably the exercise is to avoid any mutation on the original array.

Comment: @Ele I tried it without a reference/clone first, but the same thing happened. I thought the problem was happening because I was mutating the original array. Turns out I was mutating it anyway by not creating a real clone like Ele mentioned. Still can't figure out why the indexes are skipping like that though if you don't use a clone.

Comment: @ NinaScholz I tried it without a reference/clone first, but the same thing happened. I thought the problem was happening because I was mutating the original array. Turns out I was mutating it anyway by not creating a real clone like Ele mentioned. Still can't figure out why the indexes are skipping like that though if you don't use a clone.

Answer (score 0):

You code does not work as desired, because you change the index for unshifting the value. It is starting from the last index and going to zero. The result is some missing values.

By taking always the last index, you get the wanted result.

---

*I would not use one array as source and manipulate another array, with the same object reference. For keeping a consistent approach, I would use only one of it.*

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let steps = 2
let hold = arr
let indlength = arr.length - 1
for (let i = indlength; i > indlength - steps; i--) {
  console.log(hold.join(' '));
  hold.unshift(hold[indlength]); // take the last value and use hold instead of arr
  hold.pop();
}

console.log(hold.join(' '));
```

A siplified version, is to pop (the last value) and unshift it (at the front of the array). The length of the array is constant.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    steps = 2,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    console.log(array.join(' '));
    array.unshift(array.pop());        
}

console.log(array.join(' '));
```

Comment: You should explain what was wrong with his code, not just post your own code. Valid ways to rotate an array can be found in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985260/javascript-array-rotate

Comment: @Barmar, please see edit.

Comment: Thank you @Nina Scholz I made it super complicated for myself for no reason

Answer (score 0):

In your code problem is you're using reference of arr in `let hold = arr`.

[**Ele's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54832773/9624435) has already added a working snippet of your code.

Other way of doing is using [**splice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [**concat**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
let steps = 2
let part1 = arr.splice(-steps)

console.log(part1.concat(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have described why your code isn't working.  One simple non-mutating alternative is

```js
const rotate = (steps, arr) => arr.slice(-steps).concat(arr.slice(0, -steps))

console.log(rotate(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
console.log(rotate(-1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

If you wanted to rotate in the other direction, you could drop the negation signs.

This would fail if `steps` is larger than the length of the array.  If you want it to keep rotating then, it's not much more difficult:

```
const rotate = (steps, arr) => 
  arr.slice(-(steps % arr.length)).concat(arr.slice(0, -(steps % arr.length)))
```