# Rotate an array at a specific index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a a position and an array of users

```
const position = 2
const users = ["John", "Mary", "Daniel", "Michael"]
```

I want to generate a new array (or reorder it) starting from the position.

In the case of position = **2** the generated array should be

```
users = ["Daniel", "Michael", "John", "Mary"]
```

In the case of position = **3** the generated array should be

```
users = ["Michael", "John", "Mary", "Daniel"]
```

In the case of position **0** (no changes) the generated array should left intact

```
const users = ["John", "Mary", "Daniel", "Michael"]
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotate the elements in an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985260/rotate-the-elements-in-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `map()` or `Array.from()` to make a new array from the index + your offset using the modulus operator to wrap around:

```js
const position = 2
const users = ["John", "Mary", "Daniel", "Michael"]

const rotate = (arr, position) => 
   Array.from(arr, (_, index) => arr[(index + position) % arr.length])


console.log(rotate(users, 0))
console.log(rotate(users, 1))
console.log(rotate(users, 2))
console.log(rotate(users, 3))
```

Comment: @ggorlen I don't think so, however, I felt like `map()` was (only a little) semantically  wrong.

Comment: Gotcha. I forgot that `Array.from` does mapping.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array#slice` from `0..pos` and from `pos..length` to divide the array into two chunks at the split index. Then swap the chunks and either spread or `concat` the two subarrays back together. Take the mod of the position to keep the rotation in-bounds.

```js
const rotate = (arr, i) => {
  i %= arr.length;
  return [...arr.slice(i), ...arr.slice(0, i)];
};

for (let i = -1; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(rotate(["John", "Mary", "Daniel", "Michael"], i));
}
```

Comment: I like that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do that.

```
function reorder(arr, pos){
   var output = [];
   for(var i = pos;i<arr.length;i++){
      output.push(arr[i]);
   }

   for(var i = 0;i<pos;i++){
      output.push(arr[i]);
   }

   return output;
}
```

Not sure how efficient is this. There must be better ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) + [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/push) combinaison

```
users.push(users.shift());
```

...and then loop it by the position number.

```js
const users = ["John", "Mary", "Daniel", "Michael"];
let position;

function rotate(array, index){
  for(let i = 0; i < index; i++){
    array.push(array.shift());
  }
  console.log(`Position: ${index}`);
  console.log(array);
}

// Test Zone
position = 0;
rotate(users, position);
position = 1;
rotate(users, position);
position = 2;
rotate(users, position);
position = 3;
rotate(users, position);
```