# How to get future items and past items by specific index like in a carousel

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, carousel

I'm trying to create a custom carousel.
And I'm stuck with the algorithm.
I need to get future and past items by specific index.

Carousel can move around infinitely.

Example:
var exampleArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

slice(exampleArray, 0); -->> currentItem = [1], futureItems = [2,3,4,5], pastItems = [6,7,8,9] 
slice(exampleArray, 4); -->> currentItem = [5], futureItems = [6,7,8,9], pastItems = [1,2,3,4] 
slice(exampleArray, 7); -->> currentItem = [8], futureItems = [9,1,2,3], pastItems = [4,5,6,7]

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Cyrille Pontvieux 

I was able to get future items by doing this 
`var rightEndItems = arr.slice(index + 1, index + Math.ceil(arr.length / 2));
var rightStartItems = arr.slice(0, Math.floor(arr.length / 2) - rightEndItems.length); 

 var futureItems = [...rightEndItems, ...rightStartItems]; `

But stuck with past items

Comment: Please always add all relevant details to your question via [edit]. (Then delete your comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of the solutions to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985260/rotate-the-elements-in-an-array-in-javascript) (I like @mickmackusa's) to rotate the array to get the desired `currentItem` into the middle; then you can just take the slice before the middle as `pastItems`, the middle element as `currentItem`, and the slice after the middle as `futureItems`:

```js
const slicer = (arr, idx) => {
  let len = arr.length;
  let mid = Math.floor(len/2);
  let rotated = arr.slice(0);
  rotated = rotated.concat(rotated.splice(0, (mid + idx + 1) % len));
  return [rotated.slice(0, mid), [rotated[mid]], rotated.slice(mid+1)]
}

const exampleArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

[pastItems, currentItem, futureItems] = slicer(exampleArray, 0);
console.log(pastItems);
console.log(currentItem);
console.log(futureItems);

[pastItems, currentItem, futureItems] = slicer(exampleArray, 4);
console.log(pastItems);
console.log(currentItem);
console.log(futureItems);

[pastItems, currentItem, futureItems] = slicer(exampleArray, 7);
console.log(pastItems);
console.log(currentItem);
console.log(futureItems);
```