# How do I move each element in an array in 1 spot?

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this is a pretty basic question, but I never had this problem before. I'll show what I mean in a pretty basic way:

Let's say I have the array [1, 2, 3]. How can I turn it into [3, 1, 2] or [2, 3, 1] (move each element 1 to the right or the left)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: unshift, then push.

Comment: You need rotate operation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985260/rotate-the-elements-in-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: Rotate Left: `array.push(array.shift())`,  Rotate Right `array.unshift(a.pop())`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var x = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(x);

// shift right
x.unshift(x.pop());

console.log(x);

// shift left

x.push(x.shift());

console.log(x);
```

Check [here](https://alligator.io/js/push-pop-shift-unshift-array-methods/) to see what these methods do.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function shiftRight(arr) {
  if (arr.length < 2) return arr;
  return [arr[arr.length-1], ...arr.splice(0, arr.length - 1)];
}
function shiftLeft(arr) {
  if (arr.length < 2) return arr;
  return [...arr.splice(1, arr.length - 1), arr[0]];
}
console.log(shiftLeft([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(shiftRight([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```