# Is there a way to swap positions of 3 objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function which returns an array of objects like this

```
const allGreen = _.filter(
sidebarLinks,
side => !isServicePage(side.slug.current)
```

);

[image]

I'm trying to swap positions of these object.

- The first object should be at the last position.
- The second object should be the first one
- The third object should be in the middle

Comment: Length of array is static?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotate the elements in an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985260/rotate-the-elements-in-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Where is your problem, what have you tried? If it is always three elements, and the indices are known (even 0-2 here), this seems quite straight forward.

Comment: `([first, ...rest]) => [...rest, first]`

Comment: The array is static yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to remove the first object, and place it at the last position:

```js
const allGreen = _.filter(
  sidebarLinks,
  side => !isServicePage(side.slug.current)
);

allGreen.push(allGreen.shift());
```

The method [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)
of `Array` removes the first element, and returns it.

The method [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
adds one or more elements at the end of an array.