# Rotate the array by d elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have written a code for rotating a 1-D array by d elements but I just wondering if there is any shorter way to write this code?
for instance:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] , d = 3
newArr = [4,5,6,7,1,2,3]
```

```
const arrayRotation=(arr,d)=>{
    var k = arr.slice(d) 
    var m = new Set(k)
    var diff = ([...arr].filter(x=>!m.has(x)))
    return k.concat(diff)
}
```

I had to use Set so I can filter the difference between 2 arrays. Is there any better way ( complexity wise) to solve this problem?

Comment: `const newArr = [...arr.slice(d % arr.length), ...arr.slice(0, d % arr.length)]`

Comment: Duplicate: [Rotate the elements in an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985260/rotate-the-elements-in-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Please always search for existing questions first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `slice` twice and concatenate the subarrays:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], d = 3;
const newArr = [...arr.slice(d % arr.length), ...arr.slice(0, d % arr.length)];

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming D is positive you can just use the index to map old idx => new idx.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
const rot = 3;
const newArr = arr.map((el, idx) => arr[(idx+rot)%arr.length])
console.info(newArr);
>>> [4,5,6,7,1,2,3]
```